# What programming languages have been created by CGCC users?

Tags: discussion, languages

Language-creation has become a popular activity on CGCC.  A decent portion of answers, especially [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) answers, are written in languages invented by the community.  These are also languages that might be unfamiliar to this site's wider viewing audience.

What languages (esoteric, golfing, or not) have been created by our users?  For each language, please include some of the following details:

- Language name and creator
- Links to resources, like documentation and interpreter
- A brief description of the language, some of its main concepts and features, and its history

---

#### List of languages

```js
function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=meta.codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=meta.codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var a=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(a="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var r=a.match(SCORE_REG);r?e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+r[2],language:r[1],link:s.share_link}):console.log(a)}),e.sort(function(e,s){var a=e.size,r=s.size;return a-r});var s={},a=1,r=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=r&&(n=a),r=e.size,++a;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;o=jQuery("<a>"+o+"</a>").text(),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,lang_raw:o,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang_raw.toLowerCase()>s.lang_raw.toLowerCase()?1:e.lang_raw.toLowerCase()<s.lang_raw.toLowerCase()?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var QUESTION_ID=6918,ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",OVERRIDE_USER=2867,answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n]+)\s*<\/h\d>/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src=https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js></script><link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"><div id=language-list><h2>Languages by CGCC Users</h2><table class=language-list><thead><tr><td>Language<td>User<tbody id=languages></table></div><table style=display:none><tbody id=answer-template><tr><td>{{PLACE}}<td>{{NAME}}<td>{{LANGUAGE}}<td>{{SIZE}}<td><a href={{LINK}}>Link</a></table><table style=display:none><tbody id=language-template><tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}<td>{{NAME}}<td><a href={{LINK}}>Link</a></table>
```

Comment: Todo: Add [2D matching](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47311/language-design-2-d-pattern-matching) languages and every language Calvin makes up for golf questions

Comment: Do languages whose only non-proprietary interpreters were created by PPCG users count?

Comment: The title is somewhat misleading. Do general purpose languages not related to golfing still count when they have been created by PPCG users? The title suggests yes, but mostly (and naturally) the answers relate to golfing.

Comment: @minxomat This question is open to *all* languages created by PPCG users.

Comment: @bmarks I say you could go ahead and post it,  specifically mentioning the interpreter.

Comment: @PhiNotPi A suggestion: Implement a snippet in your question to list the languages. This site is quite long.

Comment: @minxomat Done.

Comment: A quick note about the snippet: **User** means the person who posted about it here, not necessarily the user who created the language. Example: I did not create Ostrich, I merely posted it here.

Comment: @AlexA. Maybe we could add a formatting guide, and suggest that the inventor be added in the header?

Comment: @BetaDecay Yeah I had thought about that. Language name, creator, and year. Up to Phi though.

Comment: @Adnan 05AB1E should be on here.

Comment: Can I post mine here if I have several alternative names?

Answer (score 65):

## Hexagony

Hexagony was created by me, Martin Büttner, in September 2015.

As far as I know it is the first two-dimensional programming language which operates on a hexagonal grid (instead of the usual rectangular grid). To make matters worse, opposite edges of the grid wrap around, making the topology of the source code a weird twisted torus. To make matters *worst*, the memory model is also a hexagonal grid, where each *edge* holds an integer value. Considering these things, I think the name (being a portmanteau of "hexagon" and "agony") is completely justified.

My [prime checker](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/57706/8478) and the [Hexagony self-unfolder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66967/8478) contain fairly detailed explanations of the language's quirks and show how to program in it.

- [**GitHub repository**](https://github.com/mbuettner/hexagony). Includes interpreter (Ruby), language specification, example programs and issue tracker.
- [**Esolangs page**](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Hexagony). Largely a copy of the README.md on GitHub.
- [**Esoteric IDE**](https://github.com/Timwi/EsotericIDE/) by [Timwi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/668/timwi) which contains another implementation (C#) and **a graphical debugger** (yep).
- [**Hexagony Colorer**](https://github.com/Timwi/HexagonyColorer) also by Timwi. This is a tool which can be used to annotate execution paths in Hexagony source code. See [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58515/8478) for an example of the result.
- [**Try it online!**](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/) (by [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis)) backed by the Ruby interpreter.
- [**Showcase your language entry**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66407/8478) (written by [Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34388/adnan)).

Comment: +1. This language hurts my brain.

Comment: Martin, how long did it take you to create/learn?

Comment: @mbomb007 Create: I think I designed the largest part of the spec over a handful of days and then implemented the ruby interpreter in half a day or so. Learn: well... I designed it, so I know how it works, but I'm still figuring out how to make use of these features, and how to golf them properly.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I wonder if you could easily extend/reduce your language to different shapes or dimensions. Like Pentagony, or Septagony. Maybe a 3D version...

Comment: @MartinBüttner (Yes, I know they wouldn't wrap around the same way, if at all)

Comment: @mbomb007 the issue is that it's not possible to construct a periodic tiling with fivefold or sevenfold rotational symmetry, so you can't just transfer the same concept to pentagons or heptagons. However, in my list of future language ideas there's the concept of using an aperiodic Penrose tiling (which has fivefold symmetry), but I need to sort out how to layout the code, and I want to tackle some simpler tilings (like triangular) first. Even for this I don't *want* to make them Hexagony derivatives, but would rather come up with new mechanics.

Comment: I was thinking about creating a language on triangular grid, too. I can’t wait to see yours.

Comment: @ML It's what I'm currently working on, but it's turning out to be quite ambitious, so there's a still a chance you can beat me to that. ;)

Comment: @MartinBüttner I doubt I’ll beat you. You are far better at programming, and I’m still trying to optimize my beeswax code. I’d like to come up with a really usable debugger for that before I start working on another project ;)

Comment: "Build a Befunge program to convert Hexagony code into Befunge".

Comment: @JoeZ. Best of luck.

Comment: @JoeZ. "Build a Hexagony program to convert Befunge code into Hexagony."

Comment: Voting to close as unclear because I got it confused with Hexagon**y**, not Hex**agony**. :)

Comment: ["I implemented the language two days ago (and designed it over two or three days before that). And yes, I'll definitely add an esolangs page, but I think the spec isn't 100% stable yet (there are still 3 unassigned commands for instance). Once I feel that it's more stable, I'll add it to both esolangs and our meta post."](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/57706/52210) You've made this programming language in just 4-5 days?! o.Ô Just wow.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I did (same for Labyrinth, I think), but for some reason ever since then it's taken me weeks or months to complete new language ideas (I've actually only completed two languages since then but there's a growing backlog of other ideas that take forever to sort out). Somehow for Hexagony and Labyrinth everything just fell into place quite neatly.

Answer (score 63):

## [Mornington Crescent](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Mornington_Crescent)

A joke language I (Timwi) created based on [*Mornington Crescent* from *I'm Sorry I Haven't a Clue*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mornington_Crescent_%28game%29). The program is executed by moving from station to station on the London Underground, starting and ending at Mornington Crescent. [Martin](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/8478) wrote a [“Hello, World!”](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/57064/30525) and a [primality checker](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58257/668) in this.

[image: Location of Mornington Crescent on the London Tube]

Comment: Unfortunately, language extensions typically cost millions of pounds and require lots of digging.

Comment: @Comintern And let's not mention the execution time...

Comment: A language fungi can be good at! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GwKuFREOgmo

Comment: I'll make a move to **Aldgate**.

Answer (score 57):

## Funciton

([esolangs](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Funciton) • [interpreter](https://github.com/Timwi/Funciton))

Created by me and my personal favourite. This is a 2D language that uses Unicode box-drawing characters to create programs that resemble flowcharts, but the semantics are actually closer to that of a functional language than an actual flowchart. It has only five built-in operations (NAND, shift-left, less-than, function invocation and lambda expressions) and only one datatype (the arbitrary-size integer) and all the useful functions are implemented in terms of this. There is an entire library of functions for arithmetic, string handling, lists and lazy-evaluated sequences.

Example: The Factorial Function

```
                   ╓───╖
                   ║ ! ║
                   ╙─┬─╜   ┌───╖  ╔═══╗
               ┌─────┴─────┤ > ╟──╢ 2 ║
               │           ╘═╤═╝  ╚═══╝
 ╔════╗  ┌───╖ │             │
 ║ −1 ╟──┤ + ╟─┴─┐           │
 ╚════╝  ╘═╤═╝   │           │
         ┌─┴─╖   │    ╔═══╗  │
         │ ! ║   │    ║ 1 ║  │
         ╘═╤═╝   │    ╚═╤═╝  │
           │   ┌─┴─╖  ┌─┴─╖  │
           │   │ × ╟──┤ ? ╟──┘
           │   ╘═╤═╝  ╘═╤═╝
           └─────┘      │
```

Another example where I actually tried to *golf* in this language: [*Render “Digital Clock Style” Numbers*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2499/668)

Comment: Interesting language. You should create a challenge that involves golfing Funciton programs...

Comment: Also, this is probably one of the coolest-looking languages I've ever seen.

Comment: I glanced at the source code. This may have the most complex interpreter of any esolang out there.

Comment: Woah, you made this? I've seen it around on esolangs and such; never knew it was created by a fellow PPCGian ;)

Comment: Some time ago, I clicked "random page" on Esolang and found this. Instant love.  Now this is *esoteric*!

Comment: [Won't you take me down to Funciton](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=SsRZLA_JzNE)

Comment: I love this language, but it never displays right on mobile.

Answer (score 44):

## Pyth

Pyth was created in June 2014 by me, isaacg. Other contributors to the language include PPCG users orlp, jakube and Maltysen, as well as others.

The source code for Pyth language is hosted [on Github](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth) for anyone to see and contribute to.

An online compiler/executor is hosted [on Heroku](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/) as an alternative way to use the language.

Pyth's primary purpose is as a code-golfing language, designed to write the shortest code possible. It is a procedural language, meaning that it is based around function calls. To reduce the overhead of each function call, all functions are in prefix notation, with fixed arity.

Pyth is written in, compiles to, and was originally closely based off of Python. This was chosen to make it easier to learn for people who already knew C-style languages. However, since its creation, Pyth code has resembled Python code less and less, as the focus has become more exclusively on golfing.

To discuss and ask questions about Pyth, visit [the Pyth chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24159/pyth). Annoucements of new Pyth features will also often be located there.

Comment: How is Pyth supposed to be pronounced? `/paɪθ/` like the beginning of Python, or `/pɪθ/` (like pit but with th instead of t)?

Comment: @Fatalize Pyth is pronounced like the first syllable of pithy, `/pɪθ/`.

Comment: Meh. I think `/paɪθ/` sounds better and makes more sense, since it's abbreviated Python.

Comment: @isaacg: What's in the name?

Comment: @jvriesem As mentioned above, it's Python but shorter, making it nice and pithy.

Comment: @isaacg: Nice! (I admit...I had to look up the definition of "pithy".)

Comment: This program is written in Pyth, / A wonderful lang to golf wyth. / Though I will concede / It is harder to read, / Its dominance isn't a myth!

Comment: @DLosc Hi, my name is Pyth. / I'm shorter than grass that's been cut with a scythe. / (double time!) / Pyth is the solution to any crisis / and if left to its devices, / it slices; it dices; / entices, allspices. / (regular time) / Listen to these advices, / and you'll find that Pyth is / the solution that concises. / How nice is that?!

Answer (score 42):

## Retina

Retina was first created by me in February 2015. I continued to improve the language occasionally, and the big 1.0 release was finally done in January 2018. There will probably be a few smaller features I will add in the future, but as of this writing I have no plans for another release that's remotely as big as what we have now.

It is a regex-based programming language which I originally just wrote to be able to use a regex in code golf challenges with as little syntactic overhead as possible. The language has come quite a long way from those humble beginnings and is now a powerful string transformation tool. I still wouldn't want anyone to use it in production, as its code-golf-oriented syntax generally leads to write-only code. That said, it's perfectly usable for writing quick throwaway scripts that don't need to be maintained, and I'm using it as an invaluable productivity tool these days.

Retina isn't nearly as terse as the top-tier golfing languages, but this is partly by design. Apart from `¶`, Retina's syntax only uses ASCII characters, and its regex syntax is no terser than that of the .NET engine itself. The reason for this is that the purpose of Retina's golfiness is to reduce the bottleneck of typing speed, not to get the absolute smallest byte count, to maximise its usefulness for quickly writing scripts to manipulate text data.

- [**GitHub repository**](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina). Includes interpreter (C#), example programs and issue tracker.
- [**Language documentation**](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language) (on the GitHub wiki).
- [**Esolangs page**](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Retina). It's mostly a stub. I have no plans to mirror the language documentation on esolangs, but maybe this article could be expanded a bit some day. That said, I wouldn't even consider Retina purely an esolang. It's way too useful for that. At the same time, its syntax is arcane enough that wouldn't consider it a practical production language either. So it falls somewhere in between.
- [**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/#retina1) (by [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis)) backed by the C# interpreter.

Answer (score 34):

## CJam by aditsu

A stack-oriented language heavily inspired from GolfScript, first published in April 2014. It is written in Java, but a JavaScript interpreter is also available.

CJam has a fixed set of variable names - all single uppercase letters - and a variety of predefined operators that use 1 or 2 characters (using a distinct first character). Due to these and other features, it can eliminate most whitespace, which makes programs shorter (and harder to read).

- Project page: https://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/
- Wiki documentation and useful links: https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam/wiki/Home/
- JavaScript interpreter (works offline!): http://cjam.aditsu.net/

Answer (score 33):

### Snowman

Once I [tried to make a golfing language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6928/3808) that was still somewhat readable, kind of like GolfScript++. Then CJam happened. So I went the opposite direction, and made an anti-golfing language that is as unreadable as possible.

*end preamble*

[Snowman](https://github.com/KeyboardFire/snowman-lang) is an esolang written in C++. Its main design goal is to be as confusing as it can possibly be, while not reaching Malbolge-level and impossible to learn.

Here's a few example programs:

- ROT13

  ```
  }vg:*#96nG|#110nL,bO|#64nG'(#78nL('>
  bO,oR|:#13nA;:#109nG|#123nL,bO|#77nG
  '(#91nL('>bO,oR|:#13nS;:#;bI;bI;aMsP
  ```
- FizzBuzz

  ```
  )1vn101nR:du*_/3NmO0eQ)(#5NmO0eQ
  }~(~%@or(%nO?_/)#%@{%@tS?)aRsP@@
  "Fizz"_aRsP\"Buzz"aRsP?)10wRsP;aE
  ```

Snowman's code is much more elegant and efficient than Ostrich, it has *far* more documentation, and it has much more work put into it in general. This conclusively proves that I am at my best when writing bad code. Which is probably why I'm on this site in the first place.

Snowman has 8 variables<sup>1</sup>, arranged visually like this:

```
a b c
d   e
f g h
```

It has *Variable operators*, which are split into four categories:

- *Rotation operators* rotate the values stored in certain variables. Mnemonic: they are all symbols that can be drawn with a single stroke and only straight lines. They rotate the variables you would visually expect them to; for example, the `^` operator rotates the `d`, `b`, and `e` variables.
- *Active variable operators* toggle which variables are marked as "active," which is important later. Mnemonic: they are all symbols that contain curvy lines. Most of them toggle what you would visually expect them to as well (ex. `(` toggles `a` and `f`).

  There are some special cases: `~` inverts the currently active variables (mnemonic: NOT), `@` rotates the active variables clockwise (mnemonic: GolfScript's rotate operator), `%` reflects them across the "center" (mnemonic: `%` looks like an `o` reflected across a `/`), `?` sets all variables to inactive (mnemonic: "forget"), and `$` saves (mnemonic: `$`ave) and `&` restores the current active variables.
- *Permavar operators* have to do with "permavars," which are essentially Snowman's equivalent of "normal" variables in other languages. `*` stores to the currently active permavar, and `#` restores from it. The possible permavar names are zero or more `=`s, then either a `+` or `!`.
- *Literals* are what you expect them to be. They're simply all the rest of the characters. `: ... ;` is a literal block, `" ... "` is a literal string, and any number of digits is a literal number.

  Speaking of data types, Snowman has four of them. It has *undefined*, which is what all the variables are set to by default and cannot be interacted with. It has *numbers*, which are stored as double-precision floating points. It has *blocks*, which are simply strings of Snowman code. And finally, it has *arrays*. There is no such thing as a "string," but Snowman does have "string" operators. Strings are simply stored as arrays of ASCII codes.

And it has *Letter operators*. Letter operators are composed in the following way:

- They are, as their name suggests, made of letters. They can either be two or three letters long. If they are two letters long, the first letter is lowercase; otherwise, it is uppercase.
- The second letter's case determines whether to run the letter operator with the *consume* mode. If it is the opposite of the case of the first letter, it will *consume* its arguments, and set them to undefined. Otherwise, it will leave the arguments intact.
- The third letter, if there is one, must be the opposite of the second letter's case.

For a full list of letter operators and more extensive documentation, [see the official doc file](https://github.com/KeyboardFire/snowman-lang/blob/master/doc/snowman.md).

I probably got a bit carried away there... but hopefully now you have an idea of how exactly the language works. (I should probably incorporate parts of this answer into the Snowman documentation itself....)

---

1: This is where Snowman got its name. A snowman looks somewhat like the number `8`.

Comment: +1 for a tutorial where a simple description would have sufficed.

Comment: ♪♫ Do you wanna build a language? It doesn't have to be a language.

Comment: ♫♪ The code never bothered me anyway.

Comment: I strongly disagree: I have more than eight variables. Also, my documentation is _terrible!_ But I do agree that I am esoteric and full of bad code.

Comment: @Snowman You should create a language called Doorknob.

Answer (score 32):

## [Ziim](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Ziim)

A 2D language created by me (Timwi) consisting entirely of arrows (`← ↖ ↑` etc., `↔ ⤡` etc.). The semantics are highly concurrent. Programming simple things is extremely laborious, both because of the limited instruction set and because of the need for thread synchronization constructs. Since most systems don’t have the necessary monoscape font for all of these arrows to line up, here’s *Hello, World!* in Ziim as an image:

> [image: Hello, World! in Ziim]

Comment: Wow, you've made so many... and they're all so fascinating :)

Comment: I've seen this on esolangs before. I must say that it's as hard for me to understand as programming in Conway's Game of Life - because that's what the constructs remind me of.

Answer (score 22):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL)

MATL /'mæt.ˌl/ is a programming language based on MATLAB and suitable for code golfing.

It was created by me, Luis Mendo, in 2015. The idea [came about](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/25584017#25584017) in the StackOverflow MATLAB/Octave chatroom in September 2015. The first version was released on December 12, 2015, after having been [sandboxed and discussed](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27114740#27114740) for a couple of weeks.

Initially the compiler worked on MATLAB only. It was then adapted to work on Octave as well. Since January 14, 2016 an online compiler is available at the [**Try it Online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net) platform (thanks to [@Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis) for providing it, and to [@rayryeng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3250829/rayryeng) for his help with the process!). Also, a MATL-specific online interpreter is available at [**MATL Online**](https://matl.suever.net/) (thanks to [@Suever](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/51939/suever) for providing it!)

#### Language features

The MATL language is stack-oriented. Data are pushed onto and popped out of a stack. Functions may take a number of elements from the stack (usually those at the top) and push one or more outputs onto the stack. Reverse Polish (or postfix) notation is used.

To ease stack handling, values from the stack can also be copied and pasted using several clipboards. These are similar to variables in other stack-based code-golf programming languages.

The main goal in designing the language has been to keep it as close to MATLAB as possible. MATL includes functions equivalent to most commonly used MATLAB functions. It should be easy for a MATLAB user to start programming in MATL within minutes.

#### More information

For more information see MATL's [**Esolangs page**](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL). The documentation and compiler can be found in the **[Github repository](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL)**. Here are some interesting [**examples**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76535/36398) that illustrate language features, and some [**golfing tips**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/78152/tips-for-golfing-in-matl).

Comment: "It should be easy for a MATLAB user to start programming in MATL within minutes." Can confirm this is true. And it's probably made me better at using MATLAB effectively as well!

Answer (score 20):

## Labyrinth

Labyrinth was created by me, Martin Büttner, in August 2015.

It is two-dimensional stack-based programming language, in which programs resemble mazes. It operates on two stacks of signed arbitrary-precision integers. Control flow is determined by the layout of the maze - whenever the instruction pointer hits a junction it decides which way to take based on the top of the main stack.

Labyrinth also comes with a unique form of source code manipulation (at runtime): the four commands `>^<v` cyclically shift a single row or column by one cell. This mechanic was inspired by the German board game [*Das verrückte Labyrinth*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labyrinth_(board_game)).

The language is pretty much feature complete, except that I'm still thinking about assigning some function to the unused characters `[` and `]`. Suggestions are very welcome!

Despite fairly simple (and usable) mechanics, the language turns out to be quite interesting to golf.

- [**GitHub repository**](https://github.com/mbuettner/labyrinth). Includes interpreter (Ruby), language specification, example programs and issue tracker.
- [**Esolangs page**](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Labyrinth). Largely a copy of the README.md on GitHub.
- [**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/#labyrinth) (by [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis)) backed by the Ruby interpreter.

Comment: +1 because Das verrückte Labyrinth is my youngest son's favorite game.

Comment: @ThisGuy Ummm. Why not? It's not even that many. [You should](http://esolangs.org/wiki/User:ais523) see [some](http://esolangs.org/wiki/User:David.werecat) other [people](http://catseye.tc/node/Chris_Pressey's_Lingography).

Comment: @ThisGuy None of my languages are golfing languages (maybe Retina a little, but not really, which is also the only one that's being used with any kind of regularity). The popular golfing languages are Jelly (Dennis), 05AB1E (Adnan), Pyth (isaacg) and CJam (aditsu) (there are a few others as well).

Comment: @ThisGuy Not really, no. I have a fairly long list of language ideas I still want to work on. Unfortunately, I haven't had as much time and/or the ideas are getting more ambitious and the projects take longer, so I haven't released as many since the initial "rush" of Labyrinth, Hexagony and Brian & Chuck.

Answer (score 19):

## Marbelous

Marbelous was (to my knowledge) the first language created as a collaborative effort between several PPCG users. The [original idea](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=16935076#16935076) is due to [cjfaure](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/13702/cjfaure?tab=profile) (then known as Trimsty). It was then picked up by several other users, fleshed out and implemented. This group of users included [Nathan Merrill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20198/nathan-merrill), [overactor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/29588/overactor), [Sparr](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4787/sparr), [trichoplax](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20283/trichoplax) (then known as githubphagocyte), [es1024](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/29611/es1024), [VisualMelon](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/26981/visualmelon) and myself, Martin Büttner (sorry if I forgot anyone; just let me know and I'll add you).

The name of the language is (obviously) a pun on "marbles" and "marvelous".

Marbelous is a two-dimensional language, where the code represents a vertical board of "devices", where marbles (representing byte values) fall down the board and are modified by the devices. Each cell of the board is represented by *two* characters. Devices are essentially functions which take input from above and produce output to the sides and below. It is also possible to define your own devices as separate boards, which makes Marbelous comparably usable (some of the original authors have written libraries, e.g. for 32-bit arithmetic).

- [**GitHub repository for docs**](https://github.com/marbelous-lang/docs). Includes language specification and a few examples.
- [**GitHub repository for original Python interpreter**](https://github.com/marbelous-lang/marbelous.py). Written by Sparr. Includes many more examples.
- [**JavaScript interpreter in the form of a Stack Snippet**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/40073/making-future-posts-runnable-online-with-stack-snippets/40808#40808). Written by es1024. Includes graphical output features.
- [**Marbelous chat room**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/16230/2014/8/5), where most of the discussion about the design of the language happened (now frozen).

Comment: `trichoplax (then known as githubphagocyte)` yoo, i was wondering where githubphagocyte went

Answer (score 18):

## Stack Cats

Stack Cats was created by Sp3000 and myself, Martin Ender. The original idea is from November 2015, but the language design wasn't finalised and implemented until late May/early June 2016.

The language is a rather purist exploration of [reversible computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_computing) with a few extra twists. Any piece of code can be undone (provided it terminates) by mirroring it (which means reversing it and swapping out all brackets). This implies rather strict conditions on what operations are possible, and in fact almost every operation is in the language is an involution (i.e. a function which computes the identity when applied twice) and only three functions come in pairs (and these compute bijections).

Additionally, every program in Stack Cats has to be symmetric itself. This means that all  programs also compute involutions on the global memory state, and that every program is essentially a very simple involution transformed into some other memory state. Nevertheless, the language is Turing-complete.

- [**GitHub repository**](https://github.com/mbuettner/stackcats). Includes interpreter (Ruby), language specification, example programs and issue tracker.
- [**Esolangs page**](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Stack_Cats). Largely a copy of the README.md on GitHub. Also includes a sketch of a proof of Turing-completeness.
- [**EsotericIDE**](https://github.com/Timwi/EsotericIDE). Contains a C# interpreter and a debugger.

Comment: This looks like a neat structure. Instruction sequences as elements of a group and finding an operator such that one of the builtins under conjugation by it does what you want.

Answer (score 17):

## Ostrich

Ostrich is a concise language designed for both golfing and (moderate) readability. It was created by Doorknob in December 2014. The most recent release, v0.7.0, occurred in June 2015. Doorknob has since ceased development of the language.

The name "Ostrich" comes from the (non-code) golf term which denotes some kind of ridiculously good score that has [never been achieved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_golf#O).

It's a stack-based language with the ability to be used interactively via a REPL. It has some interesting syntactic differences from other golfing languages, such as backticks to denote strings. It has very incomplete documentation.

- [Specification and interpreter](https://github.com/KeyboardFire/ostrich-lang/releases)
- [Picture of ostriches](http://ostrichproducersofontario.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/ostrich_fam.jpg)

Comment: +1 for picture of ostriches :D

Comment: term no longer exists on the wikipedia page

Answer (score 17):

## [Sclipting](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Sclipting)

This language, invented by me (Timwi), was intended for codegolf; it’s like Golfscript, but uses Chinese characters for the instructions and Korean characters for literal strings/numbers. Most people don’t like it because most people score by bytes, not characters, and so GolfScript/CJam/Pyth still tend to win.

Example: Hello, World!

```
낆녬닆묬긅덯댦롤긐
```

Another example: [*Love calculation*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19664/668)

Comment: I would guess that "most people don't like it" comes more from "most people can't read (and write) chinese and korean characters" than from its byte-counted disadvantage.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: Well nor can I, that’s why I created [Esoteric IDE](https://github.com/Timwi/EsotericIDE)... but somehow people don’t like that either :)

Comment: How many times has someone who can read Korean and Chinese alphabets told you you've ended up spelling out an insult?

Comment: @Texenox: None yet. For the Chinese characters, I selected characters whose meaning is actually somewhat related to the operation, so this is unlikely. For the Korean, the encoding is based on the bitwise Unicode value, so once again, it’s unlikely to happen as there are over 11,000 Hangul syllables.

Comment: Fair enough, was just asking that as some sort of joke.

Answer (score 17):

### Seriously

Seriously was created by me, Mego, in November 2015, after several brainstorming sessions in The Nineteenth Byte.

Seriously is a stack-based language where every non-null byte in the code represents a command (or will eventually). Null bytes represent EOF, so they cannot be used for commands - they end code files. As such, there is no such thing as an invalid program - every sequence of bytes will do *something* (or nothing). In addition, there are no runtime errors - if a command gets different value types from the stack than it expects, it silently exits, and the stack is restored to its previous state.

There are 4 main data types in Seriously:

- Numerics (ints, floats, and complex values)
- Strings
- Lists
- Functions

The goal of Seriously is to be extremely terse, with each command having multiple overloads based on the contents of the stack. Many common operations are built-in:

- Print `Hello, World`, the lyrics to Ninety Nine Bottles of Beer, and the program's source code (quining)
- Primality testing
- Calculating the nth Fibonacci number
- The `exp(x)`, `gamma(x)`, and many other mathematical functions
- ...and many more!

Links:

- [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously)
- [Online interpreter](https://seriouslylang.herokuapp.com) (mostly works now, post an issue on GitHub if you find a bug or two million)
- [Online documentation (WIP)](http://seriously.readthedocs.org) (thanks to @phase for getting the ball rolling on this)

Comment: This is Seriously cool. :D This is the new golfing language, as far as I can see.

Comment: Why don't characters do different things depending on which type of thing they are given?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 They do. For example (using C-like notation), `R(int n)` pushes `range(1, n+1)`, `R(list a)` and `R(str a)` push `reversed(a)`, and `R(function f, list a)` calls `f` using `a` as its stack. Not every command has multiple overloads yet, because the language is still in development.

Answer (score 16):

## Brian & Chuck

Brian & Chuck was created by me, Martin Büttner, in November 2015.

It was originally created for the language-design challenge  [Create a programming language that only appears to be unusable](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/61804/8478). I had been considering the concept of a programming language with two interacting programs for a while, and the challenge seemed like a good incentive to give it a try with a very minimal instruction set. I'm quite happy with the result and will probably use the language outside of that challenge occasionally.

The language is based on [Brainfuck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck) (hence the horrible pun of a name) and took some inspiration from [Self-modifying Brainfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Self-modifying_Brainfuck), but programming in it feels quite different from both of those. The design goals were

1. The language should be Turing-complete.
2. Neither of the two subprograms should in itself (or with some trivial help from the other program) be Turing-complete.
3. Both programs together should not be Turing-complete without one program modifying the source code of the other.

I haven't proven any of those things formally, but it appears that I've at least come close to those goals.

The basic idea is that there are two Brainfuck-*like* programs, called Brian and Chuck. The catch is that Brian's memory tape acts as Chuck's source code and vice versa. Furthermore, Brian's tape head is also Chuck's instruction pointer. Only one of them is being executed at a time, starting with Brian. Only Brian can read and only Chuck can write.

The main differences from Brainfuck are a) instead of `[]` loops, the only control flow command is `?` which hands control to the other program if the current cell is non-zero and b) there are two additional commands `{` and `}` which move the tape head to the left or right until it hits a zero cell.

B&C turns out to be hard to use but not *entirely* unusable, and golfing simple programs in it is actually quite entertaining.

- [**GitHub repository**](https://github.com/mbuettner/brian-chuck). Includes interpreter (Ruby), language specification, example programs and issue tracker.
- [**Esolangs page**](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brian_%26_Chuck). Largely a copy of the README.md on GitHub.

Answer (score 16):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak)

Brain-Flak is a language designed by me, DJMcMayhem, and written as a collaboration between me and two other users, [@Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/wheat-wizard), and [@1000000000](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20059/1000000000).

When your [Stack Overflows](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/S/stack.html), you forget whatever you were talking about. If this happens *very badly*, to the point where you can no longer speak straight, we call this a *"Flak-Overstow"*. This language is stack based, designed to hurt your brain, and very similar to Brainf*ck, so it seemed appropriate to name it "Brain-Flak".

An online interpreter can be found at [brain-flak.tryitonline.net](http://brain-flak.tryitonline.net/)

## Design

Shortly after I wrote [Are the brackets fully matched?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77138/are-the-brackets-fully-matched), it made me wonder how much information you can store with only matched brackets. One thing that stood out to me, was that even though you only have 4 "atoms" of sorts:

```
(){}[]<>
```

you really have 8 units of information to convey, since each of these bracket types can be empty, or have other brackets in between, which are fundamentally different pieces of information. So, I decided to write a language that only allowed for matched brackets, and where empty brackets convey something different than brackets with other brackets inside of them.

One other thing that influenced the design, was annoyance at brainf*cks inability to easily process decimal numbers. Taking IO in ASCII is very obnoxious, so Brain-Flak handles all inputs and outputs in decimal by default. In August 2016, I added an "ASCII mode", where IO functions identical to brainf*ck.

## Overview

(Copied from the github README)

Brain-Flak has two stacks, known as 'left' and 'right'. The active stack starts at left. If an empty stack is popped, it will return 0. That's it. No other variables. When the program starts, each command line argument is pushed on to the active stack.

The only valid characters in a Brain-Flak program are `()[]{}<>`, and they must always be balanced. There are two types of functions: Nilads and Monads. A nilad is a function that takes 0 arguments. Here are all of the nilads:

- `()` Evaluates to one.
- `[]` Evaluates to the height of the current stack.
- `{}` Pop the active stack. Evaluates to the popped value.
- `<>` Toggle the active stack. Evaluates to zero.

These are concatenated together when they are evaluated. So if we had a '3' on top of the active stack, this snippet:

```
()(){}
```

would evaluate to `1 + 1 + active.pop()` which would evaluate to 5.

The monads take one argument, a chunk of Brain-Flak code. Here are all of the monads:

- `(n)` Push 'n' on the active stack.
- `[n]` Evaluates to negative 'n'
- `{foo}` While zero is not on the top of the stack, do foo.
- `<foo>` Execute foo, but evaluate it as 0.

These functions will also return the value inside of them, so

```
(()()())
```

Will push 3 but

```
((()()()))
```

Will push 3 twice.

The `{}` will evaluate to the sum of all runs. So if we had '3' and '4' on the top of the stack:

```
{{}}
```

would evaluate as 7.

When the program is done executing, each value left on the active stack is printed, with a newline between. Values on the other stack are ignored.

Answer (score 14):

## ???

This language is a trivial Brainfuck substitution created by Alex A. (me) and BrainSteel in August 2015. It uses punctuation in place of the usual BF commands so that it may be embedded in any sort of usual human-written text and go unnoticed. Otherwise its only distinctions from BF are that it cannot travel left of the starting cell and brackets use the same character but with a toggle character to switch between open and closed.

It was created to be annoying for [The Programming Language Quiz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54807/the-programming-language-quiz), since uncracked answers use ??? in place of the language name.

- [Esolangs page](https://esolangs.org/wiki/%3F%3F%3F)
- [Original C++ implementation](https://github.com/ararslan/qqq-lang)
- [BrainSteel's improved C implementation with BF <-> ??? translator](https://github.com/BrainSteel/BrainF-k)
- [Dennis' awesome Piet/??? polyglot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54936/20469)

Answer (score 13):

## [Jelly](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Jelly)

### By elected moderator, [Dennis ♦](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis)

**From the [wiki](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki):**

Jelly is a [tacit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming),  programming language based on [J](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J_%28programming_language%29): its *raison d'être* is solving programs in the lowest possible byte count.

Answer (score 12):

## [ಠ_ಠ](https://github.com/molarmanful/-_-)

*The most disapproving coding language on the Internet!*

- [Interpreter](https://codepen.io/molarmanful/full/gajxjX)
- [Documentation](https://github.com/molarmanful/-_-/wiki/Documentation)

Oh yeah, this one's great. It was made by me beginning of November 2015 over the span of a few days. It's stack-based, like most code-golfing languages, but it's meant for general-purpose use, not code-golf. In addition, it's a line-jumping program, meaning that you go to specific lines rather than labels (like in BASIC); it might be the first of its kind! ಠ_ಠ also has [the most versatile conditional statement of any language](https://github.com/molarmanful/-_-/wiki/Documentation#conditional-statements), and it features a [useless operator](https://github.com/molarmanful/-_-/wiki/Documentation#the-useless-operator).

### Quick Example

```
ಠ_ಠ
```

A simple `cat` program.

Comment: Re versatile conditionals: check out [ARM assembler's conditional execution](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204j/Cihbjcag.html).

Comment: Is `_` shorter? 1 byte.

Comment: @RikerW Sure, but it isn't as cool. (I really need to fix up the interpreter, that's a bug :P)

Comment: Hey, um, your interpreter expired. You still have it locally?

Comment: The interpreter still works for me... although https://codepen.io/molarmanful/full/gajxjX is an alternative link in case.

Answer (score 12):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V)

V, short for vim and pronounced "vee" is a golfing language designed by me. V operates by performing transformations on a giant 2D array of strings. Although all of the builtins are fairly simple and trivial operations, such as `dw`, (d)elete a (w)ord, or `fn`, (f)ind the next occurrence of the character (n), they are very modular and can be composed into larger commands. For example:

```
ò                 "Recursively:
           "Ad    "Delete into register 'a'
          2   tn  "until the second occurrence of 'n'
 :g/regex/        "on every line where 'regex' matches somewhere on that line.
```

---

A little backstory on the language. Vim is my favorite text editor. I *love* tinkering with vim, configuring vim, playing with vim plugins, writing vim plugins, answering questions on vi.se, etc. In February of 2016, I wrote [an answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70970/31716) to a code-golf question in vim, which kinda blew my mind since I had not ever used vim as a "programming language" before. I started using vim for code-golf more and more. After tinkering with it enough, I realized it's not just *usable* for string based challenges, it's **competitive** at string based challenges!

Even though vim has no concept of numbers, it is even turing complete through it's use of recursive macros and the increment `<C-a>` and decrement `<C-x>` commands. However, it's kind of a pain to work with vim for anything beyond the simplest of challenges.

- Vim's concept of conditionals is hacky at best, and requires a lot of boilerplate code
- Taking input is a pain, since you have to manually type the input into a vim buffer at the start of a program, and then save the output at the end of the program. Running the program is also a pain since it's not automated and some minor details can throw the whole thing off. You also have to manually specify launching vim with no loaded options or info for the submission to be valid.
- Vim's handling of numbers is **abysmal**.

V was written to overcome all of these problems. A lot of these problems are still there, since V is definitely a work in progress, but some drastic improvements are already there. The biggest improvement is the automation. You don't have to manually type the program to run it!

Another improvement is the shortening of common vim idioms that take too many bytes. For example, to execute `foo` until it throws an error in vim, you can do this with

```
qqfoo@qq@q
```

This program has a whopping **seven bytes** of purely boilerplate code! And also, if a user less familiar with vim tries to test this, and forgets to launch vim with no loaded settings, this will cause undefined behavior. Completely unacceptable for code-golf. In V, this is brought down to

```
òfooò
```

With no undefined behavior. Although the second `ò` is implicit, so the real program would be

```
òfoo
```

Regexes are also *drastically* shortened, and a global stack plus some simple math operations are in progress.

Answer (score 11):

## Help, WarDoq!

This esoteric language was created by me, Dennis, in August 2015.

It consists solely of 16 one-byte built-ins that print common variations of the string **Hello, World!** two built-ins for quining, two for addition an two for primality testing.

It was designed to be very competitive in [hello-world](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hello-world) challenges with the least possible effort to satisfy [our definition of programming language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2073).

- [Specification and offline interpreter](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Help,_WarDoq!)
- [Online interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=l%3AQ%7B%22HhEeLlOoWwRrDd%2C!AaPpQq%22Q%7C%5B%22Hh%22%22ello%22a%5B'%2CL%5DSa%22Ww%22%22orld%22a%5B'!L%5D%5D%3Am*%3A%60%5B%7Briri%2B%7D%7Briri%5E%7D%7Brimp%7D%7Brizmp%7DQ%60Q%7B%5C%2B%7D*%60L%5D%2Ber%3A~N*%7D%3AH~)

Answer (score 11):

## Brachylog

Brachylog is a declarative code golf language created by me, Fatalize, in summer 2015.

Brachylog is intended to be a short-handed version of Prolog (of SWI-Prolog, specifically), which allows to chain predicates using implicit variables, implicit unification and implicit logic `AND`.

**[GitHub Repository](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog)**, which contains the Prolog transpiler and the Wiki.

Comment: This sounds extremely interesting! I hope that you will find the time and motivation to resume working on this, especially with making more declarative arithmetic available. This would make your project an even more powerful and interesting language for golfers!

Comment: @mat I might come back to it, but I would also like to redo the parser, which takes time. Since I came up with the grammar on the spot, some things aren't parsed as you would expect, some things aren't as elegant as they could be and the parser code is a mess.

Comment: Sounds about like every serious Prolog project :-)

Answer (score 11):

## SnakeEx

Created by myself (BMacZero).

SnakeEx was created for the [Language Design: 2-D Pattern Matching](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/47555/32671) challenge. It uses a regex-like syntax to detect matches in a two-dimensional block of text.

[Online Interpreter](http://www.brianmacintosh.com/snakeex/) - [Full Language Spec](http://www.brianmacintosh.com/snakeex/spec.html) - [Javascript Source](http://www.brianmacintosh.com/snakeex/snake-ex.js)

[image: interpreter screenshot]

A SnakeEx programs defines a number of "snakes", which are like regexes that can move through the text in any 2D direction rather than just left-to-right. Snakes can be called like functions, allowing recursion.

**Examples:**

**Hello World**(ish): matches the string "Hello, World!" going in any direction (crossword-style)

```
m:<*>Hello, World\!
```

**Maze Solver**: finds all routes through an ASCII maze where the walkable space is periods

```
m{E}:$(<P>\.)+$
```

**[Counting Loops](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48097/ascii-topology-pt-1-can-i-count-on-you/48260#48260)**: counts the number of ASCII-art loops in the input

```
m:({e<>PE}\-[|\-]*<T>\+|[|\-]*<T>)+`\+
e:\+
```

Its primary limitation is a lack of defined output (when I solve PPCG problems with it, I usually wrap it in a Javascript function). Another area for potential improvement is matching the edges of the input (this is currently accomplished with `$`, but code that has to do this is not very elegant).

Answer (score 11):

## ∀

∀ (or "forall") is a language that piggy-backs on other golfing language to build a golf pipeline. Not sure whether to use Perl 5, Jelly, Retina or Pyth for some challenge?

Why not use all three together?

[See it on Github](https://github.com/vendethiel/forall).

This is an example ∀ program:

```
y+
pVsQN
r(\d+)
r$*#
r!`#+
nsay join '',map{chr(5+ord)}split ''
Nsay $_».succ
```

y is Jelly. p is Pyth. r is Retina. n is `perl5 -n`. N is `perl6 -n`.

An important feature is that, as long as the prefix is the same, the code is considered to be one block. You can pipe into the same language by using an empty line:

```
pVTN
pT

pQ
```

The first Pyth program is 2-lines long, the second one is a one-liner. The empty line "breaks" the chain.

Thanks a lot to all the language authors for allowing that to be possible.

Currently included:

- Pyth by @isaacg
- Retina by @MartinEnder
- Jelly by @Dennis
- Perl 5/6 by @TimToady (:P)

Comment: If you're making a direct language injection, why not use a shell-based "eval" and just run scripts through that?

Comment: Quoting and everything, as well as flexibility: I couldn't run Jelly that way.

Comment: Write files in /tmp, run them, delete. *shrug* No need for quoting.

Answer (score 10):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip)

A golfing language created by DLosc (me), first published in April 2015.

Pip is a procedural language with infix operators. It is designed to be terse but still familiar to those who know C-like languages. For instance, it shouldn't be too difficult to see why this code:

```
Fi1,6Pi*i
```

prints the squares of the numbers 1 through 5.<sup>1</sup> Pip also borrows ideas from array-based and functional programming languages.

Some interesting features of Pip:

- Numbers and strings are the same data type, Scalar. This can become a pain occasionally, but makes for a lot less typecasting and [sometimes has neat applications](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51595/16766).
- Many operators work itemwise on lists. For instance, `[1;2;3]+[4;5;6]` gives `[5;7;9]`, and `"a".[1;2;3]` gives `["a1";"a2";"a3"]`.
- By default, the contents of lists are concatenated together before printing, but there are a bunch of [command-line flags](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip/blob/master/Documentation/Command-line%20flags.md) that allow for different formats.
- Regular expressions are built in, with [a few interesting ways](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241068/16766) to shorten certain patterns.

Updates are irregular but ongoing; ideas and contributions are welcome!

- **[Github repository](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip)**.
- **[Official documentation](https://dloscutoff.github.io/pipdoc)**. Keep this handy when programming, particularly the operator precedence page.
- **[Tutorial](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip/wiki)**. Still very incomplete, but a good place for beginners to start.

Online interpreters:

- **[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?L=pip)** Last updated in 2022 (version 1.0.2).
- **[Do Stuff Online](https://dso.surge.sh/#pip)**. Up to date with the latest commit. Runs programs client-side, which means infinite loops will hang your browser.
- **[Try it online!](https://tio.run/#pip)** Last updated in 2018 (version 0.18 aka Pip Classic).
- **[Replit](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/pip)**. Up to date with the latest commit; unlike the others, uses a REPL interface and doesn't support permalinks.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Although, the code `SQ\,5` with the `-n` flag does the same thing in 5 bytes instead of 9. But that's a bit less obvious.</sub>

Answer (score 10):

## [Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy/tree/master)

#### Created by me, VTCAKAVSMoACE

> When I have a child, I will name them Vitsy, and they shall appreciate their namesake.

[Esolangs Page](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Vitsy)

Vitsy is a forced 1D language (meaning any code put on other lines is ignored*) that uses an instruction pointer to transverse code (similar to ><>). It is stack-based and very much in progress. It was released... well, today, 18th of October 2015. It does not yet have much functionality, but it is being worked on (albeit slowly).

*NOTE: As of the latest version, Vitsy now supports static methods as accessed by line number. See README for details.

*SECOND NOTE: As of the now latest version, Vitsy now supports separate "classes", where you can extend or use other [Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy) programs in accessible directories (provided a relative directory path).

*THIRD NOTE: Vitsy now has shell access and prompting functionality.

*MOAR NOTES: Vitsy now has file I/O and JS eval.

It originates from inspiration through Brainfuck, Befunge, and ><>, and a chat conversation relating to *n* dimensional languages.

It is named after a common misappropriation of the first three characters of my name into a pronounced word (ViT-C).

Documentation is fairly limited as of now, but more, clearer documentation will be created soon.

It is currently hosted on Github and I've been working on improving it literally every day of its existence so far.

### Code Examples

#### Standard Quine

```
'rd3*Z
'           Start recording as a string.

(wraps around once, capturing all the items)

'           Stop recording as a string. We now have everything recorded but the original ".
 r          Reverse the stack
  b3*       This equates the number 39 = 13*3 (in ASCII, ')
     Z      Push the entire stack to STDOUT.

Output:

'rd3*Z
```

Comment: Ah, you changed your name. Did "VTCAKAVSMoACE" stand for something?

Comment: Yes - none of it stood for VoteToClose, though. :P That came along with peoples' interpretation. @mbomb007

Comment: Your name is VTCooltoese?

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy ಠ_ಠ No.

Answer (score 10):

### Burlesque

Burlesque is a concatenative, stack-based, lazy esoteric programming language. I'm not aware of any other esoteric programming language that is lazy but I of course don't know every single esoteric programming language.

Burlesque was written by me starting in 2012 mostly during boring lectures while I was studying computer science at a local university. At that time I probably didn't have a PPCG account yet but at least today I have.

I wrote it as a tool for me to use to make doing boring homework assignments easier and faster (and funnier) but it eventually became a language used for golfing.

Like mentioned earlier Burlesque is special in the fact that it supports lazy evaluation which allows you to work with infinitely long lists in a convenient fashion. Burlesque has a huge set of built-ins but every built-in is exactly two characters long which is of course a huge disadvantage when it comes to golfing. However, the sheer amount of built-ins is enough to compensate that a little

Since it's a language intended to be used my me I do not hesitate to add more built-ins whenever I want to and I literally only care about not breaking backwards compatibility. The reason Burlesque doesn't have a "Hello world!" built-in is because such a built-in - while nice for golfing - is pretty much useless for me because it wouldn't make solving any real world problems I use Burlesque for easier.

- Webpage: http://mroman.ch/burlesque
- Rosetta Code: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Burlesque
- Github: https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque
- Esowiki: https://esolangs.org/wiki/Burlesque

Burlesque even has built-ins for distributions (statistics, such as binomial, chi-square, hypergeometric, student t and the like), built-ins for average/variance frequency analysis:

```
blsq ) "helloooooo wwwwwwworld"gw{^pSh?+}\m
"1h1e2l6o1 7w1o1r1l1d"
blsq ) "helloooooo wwwwwwworld"f:
{{7 'w} {7 'o} {3 'l} {1 'r} {1 'h} {1 'e} {1 'd} {1 ' }}
```

Some longer scripts:

```
"
 Example code for statistics.
 Calculates average, standard deviation and
 displays a frequency table.
 -- mroman, 2013
"vv
"REM: Data"vv
{4.5 3.0 5.5 5.0 5.5 4.0
 5.5 5.0 3.0 4.5 4.0 4.5
 4.0 4.0 4.5 3.5 5.0 4.0
 4.0 6.0 5.5 5.0 4.0 5.5
 3.5 2.5 4.0 4.5 5.0 4.5
 5.0 5.0 4.0 3.0 4.5 2.5
 5.5}hd
"Average: "#aav?+sh
"Standard Deviation: "#aSD?+sh
".[Frequencies].\n"#af:SP{' +]}wl?+sh
```

which produces:

```
.[Frequencies].
 9 4.0
 7 5.0
 7 4.5
 6 5.5
 3 3.0
 2 3.5
 2 2.5
 1 6.0
Standard Deviation: 0.8908106103676267
Average: 4.39189189189189
```

Comment: And it's even [pretty commonly used on anarchy golf](http://golf.shinh.org/l.rb?blsq)!

Answer (score 10):

## [TeaScript](https://github.com/vihanb/TeaScript)

TeaScript started off simple:

After months of being [plagued](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/53677/40695) by JavaScripts verbose property names, and repetitive nature. I decided it was time for a change.

That's when [TeaScript](https://github.com/vihanb/TeaScript) was born.

Most JavaScript answers use often ingenious techniques to shave off each and every byte possible but still are left behind with large byte counts with long property names such as `String.fromCharCode`.

TeaScript originally didn't have big dreams. It started off as a very simple language which exactly like JavaScript, but shorter property names.

After posting my [first](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/61621/40695) answer I realized how big of a difference this could make and so I headed off and started brewing more features.

---

Eventually, I was hardcoding many things. Features were getting cluttered and the source code was getting very cluttered. TeaScript wasn't designed for so much golfing so I completely rewrote the code with *TeaScript 2!*

TeaScript 2 adds many new features such as unicode shortcuts, a fancy interpreter, **automatic golfing**, and many more built-ins. I'm working on a *[TeaScript 3](https://github.com/vihanb/TeaScript/tree/feature-stream)* which will hopefully being TeaScript closer to competing with CJam and Pyth.

---

What makes TeaScript different is TeaScript is not just a language that compiles to JavaScript. It ***is*** JavaScript, extended.

---

Example: This outputs an array of each character code of the input:

```
Σc
```

Output for `Hello, World!`: `[72,101,108,108,111,44,32,87,111,114,108,100,33]`

---

- [Interpreter](http://vihanserver.tk/p/TeaScript/)
- [Github (you should totally star TeaScript)](https://github.com/vihanb/TeaScript)
- [Documentation](http://teascript.rtfd.org)

Comment: vihanserver.tk’s server DNS address could not be found. When I click on the teacup on the github page.

Comment: @tomdemuyt yeah, I'm sorry about that :/ I accidentally did `chown $(whoami) -R /usr/bin/` for some stupid reason so right now my server is down

Comment: No worries, as long as you know ;)

Answer (score 10):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix)

#### [GitHub repo](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix) | [Online interpreter](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix) | [Code design helper by @Downgoat](https://jsfiddle.net/vihanb/w5p8p2ms/26/embedded/result/)

Cubix is a stack-based 2D language, created by me sometime in March. Cubix differs from ordinary 2D languages in that it's not strictly 2D: **the code is wrapped around a cube.** The first thing the interpreter does is remove whitespace, then figure out the smallest cube that the code will fit onto. The code is then padded with no-ops until all six sides are filled. That means that this "Hello, World!" program:

```
./v.o;@?/"!dlroW"S',u/"Hello"
```

is exactly the same as this one:

```
      . / v
      . o ;
      @ ? /
" ! d l r o W " S ' , u
/ " H e l l o " . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . .
      . . .
      . . .
      . . .
```

Then the code is run like a 2-dimensional language, except that the IP (instruction pointer) wraps around like the code is on a cube.

Fun fact: Cubix was [almost named Würfelsprache](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28191702#28191702), but fortunately was [saved by @Downgoat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=28192184#28192184).

Comment: What's wrong with *Würfelsprache*? D:

Answer (score 10):

## Alice

Alice was created between October 2016 and April 2017 by me, with a lot of help from [Sp3000](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/21487/sp3000). It started out as "a quick one-or-two week project" just for the sake of getting something done because I wasn't making any progress with my other language ideas. Well, you can count the months yourself... I guess it's what I deserve for turning feature creep into a design goal.

Alice is a feature-rich Fungeoid with many high-level functions that make programming in it comparably doable (hopefully). I originally started working on it when Sp3000 suggested to combine two of my ideas into a single language:

1. Many 2D programming languages use `/` and `\` to reflect the instruction pointer on the 45 degree diagonal. But I figured in most fonts those characters are closer to 67.5 degrees, so they should really reflect between orthogonal and diagonal movement in some way.
2. I wanted to create a feature-rich Fungeoid where operators have different meanings depending on what direction the IP is moving, so I could overload them with even more commands.

So here we have Alice. A language in which mirrors change orthogonal movement to diagonal movement and vice-versa, and in which the language works in two very different modes depending on whether you're moving orthogonally or diagonally: in Cardinal mode (moving orthogonally), Alice is much like other Fungeoids that can only work with integers on a stack or tape (although Alice has both); in Ordinal mode (moving diagonally), Alice turns into a string processing language and now only knows about strings as a data type.

I also resolved early on to give every single printable ASCII character a distinct function in Alice. So Cardinal mode has a lot of built-ins for basic arithmetic, number theory, combinatorics and some other shenanigans. Ordinal mode has a wide variety of commands for string manipulation and set theoretic operations.

And finally, we come to the name (and theme) of the language: the language is of course named after Lewis Carroll's Alice. Much as Alice in Through the Looking-Glass, you step through mirrors to switch between two mirror universes. What this means for the language is that the two functions performed by any of the characters in the two modes, are (sometimes subtly and sometimes not so subtly) related, in terms of their effect, their theme or their structure. When a Cardinal command works with the divisors of a number, the corresponding Ordinal mode command will often do something similar with the substrings of a string. When a Cardinal command picks a random number in a range, the corresponding Ordinal command picks a random character from a string. And so on...

If you want a first taste of the language, [here is Collatz step counter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/116565/8478). For a more elaborate example that makes proper use of both modes, [see this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/149457/8478). The language repository also has some example programs.

I've got a bunch of people to thank for their help with this language. As I said above, Sp3000 has been a huge help, testing the language, giving feedback, and throwing ideas back and forth. But I've also worked in some ideas from discussions on SE: thanks to [Basic Sunset](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53880/basic-sunset), [flawr](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/24877/flawr), [Mistah Figgins](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/62574/mistah-figgins), [muddyfish](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/32686/muddyfish), [Nathan Merrill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20198/nathan-merrill), [Peter Taylor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/194/peter-taylor) and [Poke](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/51785/poke) (and probably some others whom I forgot).

- [**GitHub repository**](https://github.com/m-ender/alice). Includes language specification, reference implementation (Ruby), example programs and issue tracker.
- [**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/alice) (by [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis)) backed by the Ruby interpreter.
- [**SE Chatroom**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56891/inside-the-looking-glass). For any questions and discussions about the language, bug reports, etc. I'll usually be pingable in there.

Answer (score 9):

## Element

Element was created by PhiNotPi (me) in March of 2012.

Element is a stack-based language that was written in and compiles to Perl.  This is accomplished by a character-by-character substitution of operators with the equivalent Perl statements, with a bare minimum of additional processing for string literals (anything that isn't an operator).

The main memory structures are *two* stacks and a hash.  One stack is the main stack, which is where I/O and most operations take place.  The control stack is where Boolean operations occur and where comparison results are placed.  This control stack is used for control flow (like while loops), hence its name.  The hash is used mainly to store/recall variables.

Element is notable as being a very "simple" golfing language.  The list of operators is short (only ASCII symbols, no letters or numbers), and there isn't overloading.  There's no array support, code blocks, eval, and only a couple of string function.

This is not ongoing development.

- Official GitHub, with interpreter and "complete" documentation: https://github.com/PhiNotPi/Element
- Esolangs page with examples: http://esolangs.org/wiki/Element

Comment: It may be of interest to note that Phi wrote the entire thing using Notepad. :O

Answer (score 9):

## Bubblegum

This esoteric language was created by me, Dennis, in September 2015.

Bubblegum was designed to be unbeatable in trivial [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) challenges, which require printing a very short string or a wall of text.

While Turing complete, the actually usable features of this languages consist in decompression of [DEFLATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE) and certain [LZMA 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Markov_chain_algorithm#LZMA2_format) streams with no overhead, as well as base conversion from binary to printable ASCII.

- [Specification and interpreter (Python 3)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum)

Comment: i honestly thought it was incredible that you found two programs with the same sha-256 hash until i looked a lot closer

Comment: How is Bubblegum Turing-complete? Are you making assumptions about the set of Python programs whose SHA-256 is 5e247c455fde7711206ebaa3ad0793114b77a6d16ed0497eff8e3bf98c6dba23?

Comment: @Gilles Yes. For every Python program, there are infinitely many comments we can append, so it should be possible to change its hash to 5e...23 without affecting functionality.

Comment: @Dennis How is value “5e247c455fde7711206ebaa3ad0793114b77a6d16ed0497eff8e3bf98c6dba23” chosen? It is just a random choice? Do you know any preimage of the hash?

Comment: @v6ak That is the hash of the program that computes the addition of several inputs or does a primality check for a single one, which can be found on the esolang page.

Answer (score 9):

## Snails

I created Snails in March 2015 [for the "Language Design: 2-D Pattern Matching" question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/47495/30688). It is also known as PMA (Planar Mollusk Automaton). [Source code (C++)](https://github.com/feresum/PMA) and [documentation](https://github.com/feresum/PMA/blob/master/doc.md) are found on GitHub.

As you may have guessed, the input is treated as a 2-dimensional grid of characters. The name comes from the image of a snail moving over the grid and executing commands. The snail leaves "slime trails", which cannot be crossed later in the program. The execution flow is controlled by backtracking, as in a regex.

Its flexibility in solving different challenges is currently limited, as the only possible output is a single nonnegative integer. Nevertheless, several suitable code golf challenges have appeared since the language's creation; if it is possible to solve a challenge with 2D input in Snails, it is usually the shortest language. The *shortest* solution often has factorial complexity, making the name **Snails** doubly appropriate.

Answer (score 8):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/Japt)

**Japt** is a shortened version of **Ja**vaScri**pt**, created by me in early November 2015. [Online interpreter](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt)

Japt is heavily based off of JavaScript. After transpiling Japt's syntax features to JS, it is evaluated as vanilla JS. This allows easy building of an online interpreter. Some of the main features are:

- **One-letter functions:** each lowercase letter corresponds to a specific function, which is different on strings, arrays, and numbers.
- **String compression:** Japt [uses](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/63338/42545) the [shoco library](http://ed-von-schleck.github.io/shoco/) for string compression. Wrapping a string in backticks tells the interpreter to automatically decompress it.
- **Anonymous functions:** `XY{X+Y}` is transpiled to `function(X,Y){return X+Y}`, as is `@X+Y}`, and in some cases, simply `+`. This allows for easy creation of functions on the fly.
- **Unicode shortcuts:** All 1-byte characters from `¡` to `Ã` transpile to longer sequences of chars.
- **And much more...**

#### Check out the [vote-by-vote showcase](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/65191/42545)!

Answer (score 7):

### Perseus

Perseus is a high level compiled native (open-source) programming languages that compiles directly to x86 machine code without any external assembler or other dependencies. It was created by me and started out as an Assembler for Windows systems, now there is a team of 5ish people. The language is intended to be both easy for beginners and as bare bones as possible. Here is some code:

```
// WM_SIZE hook, changes the width and height variables on resize
func OnSize(dword hwnd, dword message, dword wparam, dword lparam) {
    cxClient = Math.LoWord(lparam)
    cyClient = Math.HiWord(lparam)
    GetClientRect(hwnd, @Area)
    return(0)
}
```

It is a do-what-you-want and write-what-you-think language and while it isn't really object oriented, it allows for the creation of some object-like structures. Perseus can compile both standalone programs and DLLs.

**Perks**

Because binaries compiled by Perseus are as small and vanilla as possible, the language is perfect for [Democoding/Sizecoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demoscene). When the compiler is combined with an advanced packer (I recommend [MEW11 SE](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Packers-Crypters-Protectors/MEW-SE.shtml)), it generally beats or equals the size of [crinkler](http://crinkler.net/)-linked C/C++ programs. Also, because the compiler is open source, you can further improve the size of binaries by tweaking the internal translation layer. The minimum compiled binary size is about 675 bytes.

Perseus may be the only language that enables users to write bytes to the compiled binary in a useful way right from [within the code](https://github.com/Perseus-Dev/Perseus-6#directbyte).

**Info**

- Working (not stable) build + Documentation + Tons of Examples: [Github](https://github.com/Perseus-Dev/Perseus-6)
- When the stable is out, you can download it (or compile in the cloud without downloading) from here: [codeperseus.com](http://codeperseus.com)

*Please note that the Perseus team is currently porting the Perseus compiler away from VB.NET (because it is way to clumsy), so the final version of Perseus 6 is not released yet, but the above works just fine. It comes with a portable Notepad++ version customized for Perseus.*

Answer (score 7):

## [Unnamed / Phi's Golfo Supreme / Compound / GolfLang](https://github.com/PhiNotPi/GolfLang)

Umm.... yeah.  I don't have a name for this yet, it's a new project.  Unfortunately most abbreviations of "Phi's Golfo Supreme" like "PGS" have been claimed by various organizations.

PGS is a golfing language, partly based off my previous language Element.  It will be primarily a stack-based language, but with several features that go against a pure stack-based paradigm. At this point, the list of intended feature is much longer than the list of current features.

### Basic syntax

There are several different types of operators/objects in PGS.

The most basic is a **scalar**, like `42` or `hi` which are simply pushed on the stack when executed, assuming normal execution.

Nest-able **arrays** can be created with `[]` like `[2[3 4][5]]`.

**"Normal" operators** like `*+/-^` pop two elements off the stack, perform that operation, and push the result onto the stack.  The actions of operators can be modified by varies "modifiers." When performed on arrays, the default action is to perform the operation pair-wise.

**Modifiers** like "1-level reduce" `|` are pushed onto a "active modifier stack" which is independent of the main stack.  Whenever an operator is performed, all applicable modifiers are removed from the active modifier stack and put in a "selected modifier stack" which is used in the process of evaluating commands.  Modifiers can be stacked.

Some **special ops** include map `:`, which marks the top item of the stack as being a `list`.  Whenever that object is used in an operation, that operation is performed on each item in the array separately.  This method of applying "maps" means that an object can used as the subject of a map even if the `:` is used early in the program, the object is buried in the stack and dug up again, and then operated on.

I am working on adding lambda expressions.  All of my work on this has been unpublished, but I basically have some form of unnestable thing working right now.

**Trivia:** This language has been written in Perl, compiles (somehow) to Perl, and was written in Notepad.

Comment: Phi's Golfo Supreme is the only *official* name.

Comment: Why don't you call it "Phig", pronounced "fig"?

Comment: ^ (Or "Phigs", which has an 's' for "supreme")

Comment: PGS is truly perfect - "Parental Guidance Suggested".

Answer (score 7):

### [Minkolang](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Minkolang)

I, El'endia Starman, created Minkolang in mid-October.

Minkolang is a stack-based semi-golfing (2+1)D language heavily inspired by Befunge and ><>. I say it's a semi-golfing language because a good number of functions are one character, but I also keep simplicity and intuitiveness in mind. Plus, the fact that there are few or no ways to work with the stack as a whole means that it can never be as concise as true golfing languages. (I.e., I can't apply a function to every element on the stack at once, though I am actually now thinking on how to do that.)

One major element that sets Minkolang apart from other 2D languages is that for loops, while loops, and recursion are directly implemented. These, combined with its stack manipulation, array storage, and reflection capabilities make it a particularly powerful 2D language.

The official interpreter is written in Python 3 and is available here: [GitHub](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang).

Answer (score 7):

### [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE)

Pyke is a stack based code golf language created by me, muddyfish, starting in February 2016. I decided to build it to test my knowledge of Python and how long it would take for me to get a basic golfing language. I got the language fully extendable in two days using a homebrew plugin system.

Each function (or node as I've called them) can do different things depending on the size of the stack, the types of objects on the stack as well as the last item on the stack.

Pyke's stack uses a first-in last-out system for managing the stack. If ever the stack isn't long enough for the current node to function, it uses the eval_or_not function which takes input from the user and tries to eval it, otherwise returning it as a string.

It uses Python 3's new argument annotations to make the typecasting easier as well as being able to get extra data for the current nodes. This extra data immediately follows the node and is constant throughout the program. It can take the form of numerics, strings or Pyke's AST.

When the program ends, it prints out the contents of the stack implicitly.

Hello World in Pyke: `"Hello, World!`

[Try Pyke here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/)

Comment: How do I install and use it? Are there any tutorials?

Answer (score 7):

## [shortC](//github.com/aaronryank/shortC)

This language was created by me in May 2017.

shortC is a "programming language" for code golfing. Frequently-used C functions/keywords are shortened into capital letters. shortC automatically inserts closing quotes, closing double-quotes, final semicolon and closing curly-braces. It only auto-inserts a semicolon before each final closing curly-brace.

Conversions that shortC performs as of 5/23/2017 UTC-23:54:

- `A` -> `int main(int argc, char **argv){`
- `B` -> `int main(`
- `C` -> `char`
- `D` -> `#define`
- `E` -> `else`
- `F` -> `if(`
- `G` -> `getchar()`
- `H` -> `switch(`
- `I` -> `int`
- `J` -> `puts(`
- `L` -> `long`
- `M` -> `strcmp(`
- `O` -> `for(`
- `P` -> `putchar(`
- `Q` -> `gets(`
- `R` -> `printf(`
- `S` -> `strlen(`
- `T` -> `return`
- `U` -> `usleep(`
- `W` -> `while(`
- `X` -> `while(1){`
- `$` -> `system(`

(there are a lot more now but I'm inactive so I'm not going to bother updating this)

Comment: I thought I might [give it a try](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168324/73111).

Answer (score 7):

## Stax

Stax is a golfing language created by me.  Unique features include:

- Compressed string literals
- Built-in rational support
- Online interactive debugger
- Code is written in ascii, but can be "packed" to a single byte character set for savings
- Two implementations: typescript and C#

It's got a [github repo](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/issues), an [online interpreter](https://staxlang.xyz/), and [documentation](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/README.md#stax).

I'll finish with Hello, World!, which uses a single compressed string literal.

```
`jaH1"jS3!
```

Answer (score 6):

## Fourier

> Fourier is a simple language which looks similar to Golfscript or CJam but is more familiar in syntax to Brainfuck.

### Introduction

Created by me, Beta Decay, the main basis of Fourier is the accumulator. This is a variable which all operators use as their main argument. Because of this, Fourier can only handle integers and so floating point arithmetic and string related operations or pretty much impossible.

Fourier has been used in a few challenges so far (and one question) but, because of PPCG's usual requirement for an output string instead of simply numbers, the programs have been extremely long and difficult to golf. This has been fairly problematic and there haven't really been any "fun" Fourier programs, so I'll show you some.

### Examples

#### Fibonacci sequence

```
1~yI~k(xoi^<k{1}{44a32a}y+x~gy~xg~yi^~i)
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/fourier#@29YV@lZl61RkZ8ZZ5NdbVhbbWKSaGyUWFupXVGXXllXkV5XmRlXl6n5/78ZAA)

Now if you are fairly familiar with the syntax of Fourier, you may be happy with this program, except for maybe the `x` at the start of the loop: this hasn't been defined before and in older versions of Fourier threw an error. Instead, all possible variables are preinitialised to zero.

The part of the code which used the most bytes was `i^<k{1}{44a32a}`. This checked to see if the iterator (defined as `i`) is below the input value. If so, then output a comma and a space. To see why this is here, see these two examples for input `5`:

Output without `i^<k{1}{44a32a}`:

```
0, 1, 1, 2, 3,
```

Output with `i^<k{1}{44a32a}`:

```
0, 1, 1, 2, 3
```

So it's really more of an aesthetic choice.

#### ASCII table

[Similar to the requirements of this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/40490/print-the-ascii-table) but only prints the printable ASCII and takes no input.

```
33~j126(j^a~j)
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/fourier#@29sXJdlaGSmkRWXWJel@f8/AA)

This is a very basic example of how to implement a for loop in Fourier: create an iterator variable and set it to your lower bound, then set the repeat loop's condition to your upper bound. All you have to do now is increment the iterator and set the iterator to the new incremented iterator.

### Others from around PPCG

By other people:

- [Obfuscated Hello World](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58570/30525)
- [Person of Interest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58364/30525)

By me:

- [Shortest infinite loop producing no output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59609/30525)
- [Halloween Golf: The 2spooky4me Challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62452/30525)
- [Print this Question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55879/30525)
- [The Mystery String Printer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/60347/30525)
- [Remapping ASCII](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58012/30525)
- [Comparing Two Numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55729/30525)
- [Is this number a prime?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/57660/30525)
- [Hello, World!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55423/30525)

More can be found [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=fourier+is%3Aa+user%3A30525).

And, finally, the question about golfing Fourier:

- [Golfing Strings in Fourier](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55384/golfing-strings-in-fourier)

### Online Interpreters

- [Try it Online!](http://fourier.tryitonline.net)
- [Try it on FourIDE!](http://beta-decay.github.io/editor)

Note that FourIDE will be updated with new functionality and bug fixes more often.

### Resources

- [Esolangs page](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fourier)
- [Github repo](https://github.com/beta-decay/Fourier)
- [Interpreter page](http://fourierlang.codeplex.com)
- [github.io page](http://beta-decay.github.io)

Answer (score 6):

## [Joe](https://github.com/JaniM/Joe)

Joe is my pet language. It is my love for functional programming and conciseness distilled into a minimal language. It has it's roots in J, from which I got many of the ideas. The language is still very much a work-in-progress, but it has shown great potential.

Joe is designed from ground up for implicit function composition and looping. That means, you should never ever need to explicitly refer to arguments of a function, nor should you ever need to explicitly write a loop of any kind. In theory, at least.

The interpreter is written in Python, but the language itself is basically uncompileable, and thus couldn't resemble Python in any way. If you have experience with APL, J, K or Q, you can pick up Joe really quickly. If not, I would recommend saving yourself from the trouble.

An example (indented lines are code):

```
   F:+2*
   F1 2 3
2 4 6
   1F1 2 3
3 5 7
   1 2 3F1 2 3
3 6 9
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Grime](https://github.com/iatorm/grime)

Grime is a declarative language based on [Boolean grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_grammar) that I created in March 2015  for the [2D pattern matching challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47311/language-design-2-d-pattern-matching).
A Grime program (more properly called *grammar*) takes in a newline-separated string, and tries to match one or more of its rectangular sub-patterns, like a regular expression but in two dimensions.
The exact output depends on flags, but you can match against the whole input, search for one sub-rectangle, search for all sub-rectangles, and return their number, positions and/or contents.
The only existing interpreter is written in Haskell.

A Grime grammar consists of one or more *definitions*, each of which defines a *nonterminal symbol* that may or may not match a given rectangular pattern.
Complex definitions can be created using simple ones, and nonterminals may recursively refer to themselves. An example grammar is

```
A=[,()]/*
P=A*|P(A/\(/A)P(A/\)/A)P
e,P
```

which matches correctly formed [Prelude](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Prelude) programs.
This means that any vertical column may contain at most one of `(` or `)` in total, and the parentheses must be matching if their vertical coordinates are ignored.
See the 2D pattern matching challenge for details.

Grime is relatively golfy on certain 2D matching problems like the above, but not so golfy on others.

Answer (score 5):

- [Github repo](https://github.com/molarmanful/ESMin)
- [Annotated source (version 2)](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/docs/interpreter2.html)
- [Interpreter (Firefox only, version 2)](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter2.html)
- [Interpreter (Firefox only, version 1)](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter.html)

is a code-golfing language I made in late October 2015. It compiles to ES6 - in fact, it's basically ES6 except with a stack, basic aliasing, and a whole lot syntax changes. Of course, it's a work-in-progress, but version 1 is stable enough for general use.

**WARNING**: The printable non-ASCII values that  uses can create disproportionate byte-to-char ratios. Treat this as a challenge of some sort.

Quick example:

```
ⒶṤć⇀⧺_
```

This outputs 1 to 100.

Comment: It should be noted that the language name is ESMin, but the characters are [blackboard-bold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackboard_bold#Usage), which aren't supported yet, for the most part.

Comment: I can see it on my Mac, though. (Not on Windows 7.)

Comment: I think instead of "unprintable ASCII values" you want to say "(printable) non-ASCII characters"?

Answer (score 5):

## [Jolf](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Jolf/)

**Jolf** is yet another JavaScript variant; is procedural, like Pyth. It's GitHub repo was made around Nov. 15. It transpiles to JavaScript.

It's a really handy tool, and I use it all the time when coding in JavaScript. Here is the [interpreter](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/)! And [some documentation](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Jolf/tree/master/docs), because you're such a nice person.

Answer (score 5):

## [AnnieFlow](http://esolangs.org/wiki/AnnieFlow)

This language was created by me, Fricative Melon, recently, though it is based on [StackFlow](http://esolangs.org/wiki/StackFlow). I liked the idea of StackFlow, but it was clunky and had no interpreter (and I didn't want to write an interpreter for it), so I made my own variation. The main idea of StackFlow is to have a fixed starting number of stacks, and a fixed number of symbols for each stack, and have all operations be popping from stack to stack and pushing symbols before each pop, with each symbol going to different stacks and pushing different symbols when popped, the inspiration for its creator being Magic the Gathering, and proving languages Turing complete by implementing it in them.

My version is completely "type" safe with no wasted bits, and every program is a valid one, if you add enough 1s to the end of it. The cat program is 11, and a program that does nothing is 01. The null program is not actually a valid program, and there are no trivial quines. The interpreter is [here](https://github.com/allenkev/annieflow).

The name is a variation of "AnyFlow" since although the current interpreter uses stacks, using another data structure is a one line change, and you could even mix and match them. There is really no fixed stackiness of the language.

This is my first "new" language, so let me know how I could improve the documentation, it may be a bit messy right now.

Answer (score 5):

## [Sesos](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/sesos)

#### By elected moderator, [Dennis ♦](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis)

Sesos is an assembly-like language based on Brainfuck. It has a code-head and data-head, and has ten basic commands:

`fwd <n>` moves the data-pointer `n` cells forward
`rwd <n>` moves the data-pointer `n` cells backward
`add <n>` adds `n` to the current cell
`sub <n>` subtracts `n` from the current cell
`get` gets a value from STDIN
`put` prints a value to STDOUT
`jmp` creates an entry point and jumps to the corresponding `jnz` or `jne`
`nop` creates an entry point
`jnz` creates an exit point and jumps to the corresponding `jmp` or `nop`
`jne` creates an exit point and jumps to a position read from STDIN if it is before EOF

It is compiled to `sasm`, or assembled Sesos, which is the used to determine the final code size.

Comment: Why not let Dennis post his own languages? This is the second time you've posted one of his languages, and this one is only 3 days old.

Comment: @Mego The question does not say that you have to post your own languages; there is nothing preventing me from posting it. I have not been aware of any other finished new esoteric languages publicly announced in chat, so it's just a coincidence that this is also Dennis'. Furthermore, I'd be happy to delete the answer so Dennis can post his own, but Dennis hasn't commented about this yet.

Comment: It just seems strange that you have now repeatedly posted other people's languages here. Did you talk to Dennis either time before posting? It's a matter of courtesy.

Comment: I've undeleted both of your posts. I'm perfectly fine with someone else posting them.

Answer (score 5):

### [Jellyfish](https://github.com/iatorm/jellyfish)

Jellyfish is a two-dimensional language created by me, Zgarb, in January 2016.
It's largely inspired by J, and the name is a combination of [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly) (another J-like language) and [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish) (pronounced "fish"; a two-dimensional esoteric language).
Jellyfish began as a [challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65661/parse-a-two-dimensional-syntax) here on PPCG, and then took on a life of its own.
It's still under active development, but you can play with it on [TIO](http://jellyfish.tryitonline.net/).
You can also discuss it in the [dedicated chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43483/jellyfish).

The standard library of Jellyfish contains mostly arithmetic and array manipulation functions, and as with J, multidimensional arrays are the only nontrivial datatype.
My plan is to re-implement a large part of the standard library of J, suitably modified for the computational model of Jellyfish, as well as any interesting features I feel like implementing.

While the standard library of Jellyfish is largely borrowed from J, the syntax is what makes it unique.
Its source code is arranged on a 2D grid, and each grid cell may contain a *value*, a *function* or an *operator*.
Values are either numeric or string literals, or special input values that are read from STDIN during execution.
A function takes as its argument the two nearest values to the south and east (if they exist), and most functions have both one-argument and two-argument forms.
Operators are second-order functions: they take one or two functions as inputs, and produce new functions, which are then called on the arguments of the original functions.
A large Jellyfish program is a complex network of function and operator calls and reused values.

Here's an example program to compute the average of a list, or `0` if the list is empty:

```
p%~/+0
 #  i
```

The `i` is replaced by input from STDIN; lists are taken in the format `[1 2 3 4]`.
The `+` is addition, and it takes arguments `i` and `0`.
Now, `/` is the *fold* operator: it takes the function `+`, and folds it over the list `0` using initial value `i` (the arguments of `+`).
This argument order is of course incorrect, so we apply the operator `~`, which flips the arguments of `/+`: it now folds `+` over the list `i` with initial value `0`; in other words, it computes the sum of `i` with default value `0`.
On the second row, the function `#` computes the length of the list `i`, and `%` divides the sum by that.
Finally, `p` prints the result of the division to STDOUT.

Answer (score 5):

## [Billiards](https://github.com/alexander-liao/java-public/tree/master/programs/ball-simulator), Created by Me (HyperNeutrino)

This link ^ includes the interpreter (in one source file) and the documentation/README.

Inspired by a challenge by PPCG User @PhiNotPi's, the concept behind this language is that you have a large setup of machines that operate on a bunch of balls carrying values which fall down through the machine.

Advantages: Looks interesting, shorter than many languages.
Disadvantages: Heavy on bytes because of all of the special characters, longer than Jelly (obviously).

Here are some examples of code you can write with it.

```
1/\
 .↑
\^/
```

Prints theoretically all ASCII characters. Step-by-step run-through:

```
The 1 creates a ball with value 1
It falls onto the first backslash, which deflects it to the right
It hits the ^ and begins levitating
It hits the . which outputs its value as per (char) value
It hits the first slash which deflects it to the right
It hits the next backslash, and since it is moving sideways, it is deflected down and ceases levitation
It hits the ↑ and its value is incremented
It hits the final slash and is deflected to the left, returning to the ^, which continues the loop.
```

This language has gone through many modifications; when I started with it, this was how you added two numbers up to `3 + 3 = 6`:

```
  a          b  
    c          d
           1    
           \_/  
             \_/
            \/  
            /\  
           _ __/
            \_/ 
             \/0
1           \\_/
\_/          _K1
  \_/      \  \/
 \/         __/ 
 /\          /  
_ __/       _   
 \_/       \__  
  \/ _______/   
 \\_/           
  _S1           
\  \/           
 __/            
  /             
 _              
\__             
 C
```

Now, you do this:

```
⇓⇓
+/
↥
```

It's so-so for golfing; it's not very short and I suspect that it lacks Turing-completeness. (I will try implementing Rule 110 on this to see if that's true. It doesn't have conditionals, so... it requires hacky workarounds such as using the metadata of a gridspace and splitting the ball for comparison and return values in order to do it).

Answer (score 4):

### STATA (free interpreter)

[STATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stata) is a statistical programming language similar to R that is commonly used for economics papers. However, since many challenges on this site require a free compiler/interpreter for valid languages, I created a partial interpreter supporting some of the commonly used golfing commands from STATA.

Currently supported commands include set obs, local, global, generate, display, replace, list, and forvalues, though each one only supports a limited subset of the corresponding proprietary STATA command.

[The free STATA interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/40073/making-future-posts-runnable-online-with-stack-snippets/47181#47181) was created in February 2015 by me, bmarks, though suggestions and edits are welcome from any user.

Answer (score 4):

## [Hassium](http://HassiumLang.com)

Hassium is a very useful interpreted programming language created in C# by myself (JacobMisirian) as the lead developer and with the help of my partner Zdimension.

Hassium contains builtin classes that include File-system IO, Networking, Drawing, Cryptography, and more.

Hassium has a syntax that stems from Python, C, and C# and contains many classes that are exactly the same to it's C# equivalent, meaning you wouldn't have to learn all the different Hassium classes if you are familiar with C#. Take the StringBuilder class for example:

```
func main () {
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("Hello ");
    sb.append("world");
    println(sb.toString());
}
```

As you may have noticed Hassium is a fully object oriented language and you can create your own classes and methods, as shown here:

```
class Person {
    func new (name) {
        this.Name = name;
    }
    func greet(this) {
        println("Hello my name is " + this.Name);
    }
}
func main () {
    slim = new Person("Slim Shady");
    slim.greet();
}
```

Hassium has support for most common elements of modern programming languages. It has the for, while (else), do while, and foreach loops as well as the usual if statements, arrays, and dictionaries. There are also LINQ-like functions and mapping.

Hassium is fairly well documented and the wiki can be found [here](https://github.com/HassiumTeam/Hassium/wiki).

On the HassiumLang.com website there is an online interpreter where you can execute code and have the output in your browser, as well as share your code with your friends.

- [**Hassium Website**](http://HassiumLang.com)
- [**Online Interpreter**](http://HassiumLang.com/Hassium)
- [**Hassium GitHub**](https://github.com/HassiumTeam/Hassium)

Answer (score 4):

## inca

[github](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/inca). Created by luser droog (aka M. Joshua Ryan). Began as an exercise in understanding the obfuscated APL calculator program known as the [incunabulum](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Essays/Incunabulum), and later adding capabilities and extensions.

**inca** exists in two distinct (more-or-less-)fully-realized versions. The original [inca.c](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/inca/blob/master/inca.c) is integer-only. [inca2](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/inca/blob/master/inca2.c) has support for char, int, and double datatypes. A third version was [begun](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/inca/blob/master/inca3.c) which collapsed under the weight of its own obfuscation. The integer version is available [online](http://baruchel.hd.free.fr/apps/apl/inca/).

All of these programs expect a 32bit environment. See the Readme files [1](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/inca/blob/master/README.md) [2](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/inca/blob/master/README2.md) [3](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/inca/blob/master/README3.md) or the [wiki](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/inca/wiki) for more usage and explanation, but it basically provides the basic pre-80s features of APL languages including dot and over operatprs which apply to user functions as well as built-ins.

It has been used in 2 challenges:

[ASCII Ice Cream](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47255/ascii-ice-cream/47289#47289)
[Generate a Universal-binary-function Lookup Table](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12103/generate-a-universal-binary-function-lookup-table/41211#41211)

And I'm designing the next version with the intent to present an amazing answer to this challenge:

[Draw the Utah Teapot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22620/draw-the-utah-teapot)

--

### olmec

The [next version](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/inca/tree/master/olmec) is partly working and will offer amazing "killer" features.

- Portability. No more `intptr_t` foolishness. Source should compile and execute on any platform which can run xterm. Tested on Cygwin64+Windows 10.
- "All" whitespace is optional (except to separate numbers). The symbol lookup is designed around *prefix-searching* so multiple defined symbols may be juxtaposed into one "identifier" which is then split at execution time. Also, all punctuation characters, indeed anything not whitespace, part of a number, a paren, a quote, or a left-arrow is considered a valid identifier. (For testing and "normal" programming, it is advisable to separate symbols with space for better readability.)
- Outer parens are optional. `3)` == `3`. `(3` == `3`. `2&+)3` == `5`.
- Idiom recognition. Since all function names are treated as identifiers, and juxtaposed identifiers are parsed at execution time, sequences of functions can be redefined. This may permit easy testing of "slow" programs by selectively replacing sequences of function symbols with faster versions.

--

Update: starting to get some results.

```
josh@LAPTOP-ILO10OOF ~/inca/olmec
$ ./olmec
        ⎕k
·¨¯<≤=≥>≠¨²_÷
◆1234567890-×
QWERTYUIOP→£≠
?⍵∈⍴∾↑↓⍳○⋆←]⍀
ASDFGHJKL:"  
⍺⌈⌊_∇∆∘'⎕º´  
ZXCVBNM«»¿   
⊂⊃∩∪⊥⊤|¶·⌿   

        a←⍳9
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
        1+3↑a)⍴¯7↓a
 0 1 0
 1 0 1

        'hello, world!'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Needs some work. :)

```
$ ./olmec
        double←2&*
&
        double5
 10
        double⍳5
 0 2 4 6 8
        'hello world'
hello world
```

Update May 2016: Implemented bracket indexing which produces *lvalues* that can be on the left of the assignment arrow.

```
        a←10 10⍴' '
        a[5;5 6 7 8 9]←'CROSS'
        a[4 5 6 7;7]←'WORD'
        a




               W    
           C R O S S
               R    
               D
```

Belated Update Sept 2016: Some months ago implemented direct definition of functions, "del" definitions with labels and branching. Current list of functions and operators: https://github.com/luser-dr00g/inca/blob/master/olmec/tables.md

Answer (score 4):

## [Milky Way](https://github.com/zachgates7/Milky-Way)

Milky Way was created by me, Zach Gates, in November of 2015. I was bored and thought that writing a language would be fun. It's an esoteric golfing language. It's written in Python 3 and is run as an executable.

---

### Facts

1. Nearly all the opcodes are destructive, meaning they remove the top-of-stack, perform their function, and push the new item back onto the stack.
2. Each line of a program has it's own stack. Each stack is initiated with two elements already on it; an empty string and zero.

   ```
   ["", 0]
   ```
3. If no output has occurred by the end of the program, the bottommost stack element will be output. For example, if the resulting stack is

   ```
   ["abc", "def"]
   ```

   then `"abc"` will be output; surrounding quotations included. This is the only setback to running a program with no output.
4. Input is taken via the command line with the `-i` option.

---

### The `Hello World!` program:

This is the standard method:

```
"Hello World!"!
```

Everything within double quotes is a string in Milky Way. The exclamation mark outputs the top-of-stack. Alternatively, the inverted exclamation mark (decimal 161), will output the top-of-stack *and* terminate the program (any opcodes following will not be executed, nor will any subsequent lines). With one extra byte, but an equal number of characters; here it is:

```
"Hello World!"¡
```

Further, the greater than sign (decimal 62) will shift the entire stack rightward. The top-of-stack will become the bottom-of-stack, thus being output upon termination. This output, however, would be invalid if the output is not allowed to include surrounding quotations (see fact 3, above). Here it is:

```
"Hello, World!">
```

---

### Truth machine

This is the shortest method I've come up with.

```
'?{0b_!_&{!}}
```

The single quote opcode reads the input from the command line. This piece: `?{...}`, is an if statement. Each piece is separated from the next by an underscore.

- Code from the opening bracket to the first underscore, `0b` in this case, is the conditional.
- Code from the first underscore to the second underscore will run if the conditional evaluates as true.
- Code from the second underscore to the closing bracket will run if the conditional evaluates as false.

In the case of this program, `0b` checks is the top-of-stack, the input, is equal to `0`. If it is, it outputs the top-of-stack a single time. If not, the top-of-stack is output for eternity, because `&{...}` constitutes a Pythonic `while True:` loop.

To read more about the meanings of different bracket sets, take a look at the [Github repository's readme](https://github.com/zachgates7/Milky-Way/blob/master/README.md).

---

### Catalog of answers

Here is a catalog of cool and significant answers that have been written in Milky Way. Each element on this list is the title of a question, while each link is the direct share-link to the answer.

Feel free to add to this list if you've written an answer you think is cool.

- ["Hello World!"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/65542/39462)
- [Implement a Truth-Machine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/65544/39462)
- [Find the absolute value of a number without built-in functions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/65753/39462)
- [Catalan Numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66166/39462)
- [Cover up zeroes in a list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/65800/39462) (LOCF imputation)
- [Conjugate in the Spanish imperfect](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68595/39462)
- ["99 Bottles of Beer"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/65594/39462)
- [The versatile integer printer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/65677/39462)
- [Mixed Number to an Improper Fraction](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66982/39462)

---

### Links

- [Github Repository](https://github.com/zachgates7/Milky-Way)

Comment: What a coincidence! My name is almost the same name as this programming language, and both this language and me are related to PPCG

Comment: @MilkyWay90 Beetlejuicing!

Comment: @GabrielMills Beetlejuicing? What's that?

Comment: @MilkyWay90 https://www.reddit.com/r/beetlejuicing/about

Comment: @GabrielMills Oh, I didn't know there was a term for that.

Answer (score 4):

### [INTERCALL](https://github.com/theksp25/INTERCALL)

I have created INTERCALL in june 2016.

Intercall is a anti-golfing language. Each code must start with a 116 character long header, to prevent code golfing.
The header is:

```
INTERCALL IS A ANTIGOLFING LANGUAGE
SO THIS HEADER IS HERE TO PREVENT GOLFING IN INTERCALL
THE PROGRAM STARTS HERE:
```

Example code (Without the header):

```
QUINE
END
```

Is just a quine.

A "Hello, World!" program can be found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/theksp25/INTERCALL/master/INTERCALL/INTERCALL/helloworld.itc).

Comment: @Downvoters why?? this is hilarious.

Answer (score 4):

### [Your Mom](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/your-mom)

Your Mom is a language that I have created after a message of mbomb007 on The Nineteenth Byte:

> I think someone should create a language called "Your Mom", just so that during an argument over which language is a better one, they can interject that "Your mom is a better language"

<sub>[Source](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30959191#30959191)</sub>

Your Mom is a stack-based golfing language using Unicode characters, and implementing the [Jelly compressor](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/your-mom/blob/master/src/jellycomp.js) (not the dictionary based compressor of Jelly), a simple compression algorithm.

Since without code, I get downvotes, here is a snippet:

```
¥€⊞@
```

Push 1 (`¥`), create a one-character function that increment the TOS (`€⊞`), and loop while the TOS is not zero (`@`).
Basically, this snippet do nothing, but could stop on integer overflow.

Comment: OK, why so many downvotes?

Comment: The name, most likely.

Comment: @Fatalize But all other posts using Your Mom have upvotes

Comment: They have upvote because of the code. Here the name of the language is taken into account for votes, since it's the presentation of the language

Answer (score 4):

## S.I.L.O.S

S.I.L.O.S is a language I created with some loose inspiration (retrospectively) from Trump Script.

---

S.I.L.O.S "Features"

1. **Arrogance** S.I.L.O.S is an arrogant name as it stands for.

   - Superb
   - Interpreted
   - Language's
   - Obviously
   - Superior
2. All of the slowness of the JVM with all of the challenge of assembly
3. Limited error messages with a default behavior of on error resume text
4. Readable while remaining a turing complete minimalistic language
5. Numbers can be used as variable names
6. No declaration needed of variables

In short S.I.L.O.S is clearly the language of the future and ought to provide speedy development. Feel free to take a look at the GitHub here.

---

https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S

Answer (score 4):

## [Woefully](https://github.com/Destructible-Watermelon/Woefully)

Woefully is a 2d language. It is named Woefully, because everyone knows that adverbs are the best language names, and also because the byte counts will be saddening. Example:

> Woefully, 1000 bytes

or something like that.

Woefully works rather differently than most programming languages, and even 2d programming languages. It originates from ideas coming from whitespace, and ideas from 2d languages, as well as, initially, hiding messages in text. the last one, because originally it was going to have letters and other characters to complement spaces, but then I changed my idea. It is based on typographical rivers.

### How it works

As I said, this language is different, it is very different to befunge or anything else. Unless it is. In which case I would be a little disappointed my brain keeps coming up with already used ideas.

Woefully uses lines of spaces as its commands.
Not this kind of line of spaces,

```
|     |
```

this kind

```
| |
| |
| |
```

specifically, this command is the A to B command, which moves a value on stack A to stack B.

As I mentioned, there are two stacks, stack A and stack B. Almost all commands that push values push to A, except dupe, and the command specifically for pushing to stack B (A to B).

Different types of lines execute different commands:

```
||| |  push operations
|| |
| |

| |
| | stack operations
| |

| |
|| |  Other stuff like i/o, and the stuff used as control flow
||| |
```

The specific command of a type of command is determined by it's length.

Push is simply push length of the push command - 3, the other two types are taken from a table, after subtracting two, and modulo'ing

Commands get concatenated together:

```
|||| |
||| |
|| |
| |
|| |
|| |
|| |
|| |
|| |
|| |    (this program prints 1 a bunch, and puts a bunch of ones on the second stack)
||| |
|||| |
||||| |
|||||| |
||||||| |
```

note that the two top commands are connected by a two long line command. two long commands are nops.

this program halts

```
| |
```

Single length paths halt the program

You can also have multiple paths (only executing a second with a special command)

```
| | |
| | | (does nothing, the second isn't even executed even if it did something)
| | |
```

There aren't any conditionals like in a regular programming language, except for the "not zero" command, which pops a value from stack A, pushes one if it isn't zero, and zero otherwise. if you combine this with a move command, you get control flow.

#### Move command

All programs without this command loop infinitely, or immediately halt

This is because there are two pointers. We have the instruction pointer, which executes commands discussed before, but there is also the char pointer. The char pointer points to a char (obviously) in the program source. It begins pointing at the first char in source. When the program starts, the instruction pointer appears at the char pointer's character, finds the first space it can, moving forward (the search including the character pointed at by char pointer). It then executes the path that space is a part of, from that space. when it reaches the end of this path, it goes back to the char pointer, and does it again. The move command changes the position of the char pointer.

Using the "not zero" command with the "move" command (and usually the multiply command to avoid actually excessive bytecounts (even this language has standards)), we can change the the path the program executes if a value in the stack is non-zero, and have Turing completeness. If you want to see what changing the path looks like, [the truth machine I made is probably your best bet.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92377/55896)

Comment: So can Woefully do anything? So far the examples haven't convinced me

Comment: I didn't want to make this post longer than it already is, but thinking about it would be possible to do something in short code

Answer (score 4):

## QBIC

QBIC is QBasic's Interpreter for Codegolf. I made it to bring QBasic into the code-golfing arena. Working on it is a ton of fun. It provides a short-hand for QBasic's expansive syntax and language constructs, and it adds a few tricks of its own.

The project can be found here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ?usp=sharing

It is built and run entirely in / through QBasic. There is (as of yet) no web-interpreter or IDE.

Samples of usage are here:
[Showcase of Languages](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44680/showcase-your-language-one-vote-at-a-time/86385#86385)

To get started with QBIC

1. Download the project to your computer
2. You probably need DOSBOX or similar to run it
3. Edit `qbic-in.txt` in <s>your favorite text editor</s> a text editor that supports QBasic's ASCII table. I use Notepad++ with the Western European / Windows-OEM character set.
4. Fire up QBasic, open and run `QBIC.BAS`
5. Enter command line parameters if necessary
6. QBIC will now run the interpreted QBasic for you.

Comment: I finally tried QBIC, and was surprised: It throws an error if I use QBasic, because it requires QuickBASIC – which I wouldn't have guessed from your description. I'm familiar with the difference, as I bought QuickBASIC 4.5 in 1990, before QBasic existed, back in MS-DOS 4.01 days. QBasic was released in 1991 with MS-DOS 5.0, and is a scaled-down version that can only interpret .BAS files, whereas QuickBASIC can also compile .BAS to .EXE. I used QB 4.5 (and later Microsoft BASIC 7.1, a successor to QuickBASIC, filenamed QBX.EXE) until transitioning to Turbo Pascal in 1994 (and later C/C++).

Answer (score 4):

## [ezfuck](https://github.com/carcigenicate/ezfuck)

I just finished ezfuck yesterday after 3 days of work. It works very similar to BrainFuck (in fact, all BrainFuck is valid ezfuck), but adds a few new commands and features:

- Adds the `*` and `\` operators
- Adds in numberic literals, and allows most commands to take them as an argument

  - `+++[>++++<-]` == `+3[>+4<-]` ~= `+3*4` (the last doesn't require a second cell)
  - `>13` == `>>>>>>>>>>>>>`
  - `,-48` sets the current cell to the number entered (its char code - 48)
- `{` and `}` allow direct control over the instruction pointer. As with `]`, the jump will only happen if the current cell value is 0.

  - `{n` will move the instruction pointer `n` commands to the left, while `}n` will move it `n` commands to the right. If `n` isn't supplied, it defaults to `1`.
  - `+{` == `+[]`
- `^` allows directly setting the value of the current cell.

  - `^6*2` sets the current cell to `6`, then multiplies it by `2`.
- `V` allows getting the current cell value to be used as an argument for a command.

  - `^6>V` sets the current cell to 6, then takes the value, and gives it to `>`. Of course, you could just write `>6`, but I figured this may have some use with some creativity.
  - Allow the user to directly control the instruction/cell pointers: `,^}V`, `,^>V`
  - `^V` is a no-op.

An uncreative "hello world":

```
^72. ^101. ^108.. ^111. ^32. ^87. ^111. ^114. ^108. ^100. ^33. ^10.
   H     e     ll     o         W     o     r     l     d    !    \n
```

Comment: I like this language. Here's a more shorter program that should print `Hello World!` (untested): `^72.+29.+7..>^111.>^32.+55.<.+3.<.-8.^33.`

Comment: @Luke Thanks :). Unfortunately I have yet to find a good use case for `{` and `}. I found them to be difficult to use at best.

Answer (score 4):

## Cubically

Cubically was created in 2017 by me, MD XF. It is built around the main piece of memory, a Rubik's Cube. To my knowledge there were (and are) no existing languages with a similar design.

A 3x3x3 memory cube (the default) begins with this initialization:

```
   000           (top face)
   000
   000
111222333444     (left, front, right, and back faces, respectively)
111222333444
111222333444
   555           (bottom face)
   555
   555
```

Each number represents a cubelet (in a 3x3x3, there are nine cubelets on each face). After performing a 90° clockwise right turn (`R1` in Cubically source), it would look like this:

```
   002
   002
   002
111225333044
111225333044
111225333044
   554
   554
   554
```

There are two other pieces of memory, which are simply registers - the notepad and the input buffer. The input buffer is read-only and always contains the most recently inputted value (values are only inputted when `$` or `@` are hit in the source). The notepad stores the result of mathematical operations.

Mathematical operations are performed on face values. A "face value" is the sum of adding all values on the given face index. For example, the face value of the top face (indexed `0`) immediately after initialization would be 0. The face value of the left face would be 9, the front would be 18, etc. The notepad (face index 6) and input buffer (face index 7) are initialized to zero.

Some mathematical operations are:

- `+x` - x specifies a face index, add its value to the notepad
- `-x` - x specifies a face index, subtract its value from the notepad (storing result in notepad)
- `_x` - x specifies a face index, modulo the notepad by its value (storing result in notepad)

## Examples

A cat program would look like this (no cube manipulations required):

```
(~-1/1=7&6@7)
(              open loop
 ~              read input to input buffer
  -1            subtract 9 from notepad
    /1          divide notepad by 9 (yielding -1)
      =7        compare notepad and input buffer for equality
        &6      exit if notepad truthy (notepad == input buffer)
          @7    print input buffer
            )  close loop
```

## More

Cubically has been developed into a mostly functional language thanks to the collective efforts of [me](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61563/md-xf?tab=profile), [TehPers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/72489/tehpers) (many bug fixes and feature ideas), [Kamil Drakari](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71434/kamil-drakari) (more bug fixes, feature requests, suggestions and algorithms) and [Destructible Lemon](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55896/destructible-lemon) (Cubically's name).

Useful links:

- [GitHub](//git.io/Cubically) / [GitHub team](//github.com/Cubically)
- [Try It Online](//tio.run/#cubically)
- [Chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62883/cubically)

Answer (score 4):

## Wumpus

Wumpus was created by me in February 2018. The language's history is actually much longer though. Back when I created Hexagony (in September 2015), I noticed that there aren't any 2D languages for either hexagonal *or* triangular grids, and ended up picking hexagons at the time. But from the beginning I intended to fill both of those gaps.

But after I designed Hexagony, the ideas for a triangular language went through many stages, some or and some less ambitious and kept putting off actually getting to work on it. Originally, I came up with the idea of calling the language *Triptych* and making it consist of three separate triangle-based structures and three separate programs (a bit like Brian & Chuck on steroids). At any given time, one of the three programs would be running, with the corresponding structure acting as the code, and the two other structures acting as data, and each program could pass control off to the other structures. And each of those three programs was supposed to be running a different programming paradigm. But then the design for one of those three spiralled a bit out of control, and I decided to turn it into its own language – that one is still on the backlog, because it's a fairly ambitious idea. But the other two were the triangular grid and the icosahedron.

After removing one of the three subprograms, I decided to drop the idea of having multiple programs with different paradigms and settled on making this a more traditional Fungeoid on a triangular grid but using the icosahedron as a data structure. After Hexagony, I didn't want to force this kind of mind bending memory model onto the programmer, so I also gave the language a stack and made it the primary data structure (the icosahedron acts as 20 registers, which are largely optional, but can make some things more convenient if you do figure out their topology).

So that's what I ended up with: (what I believe is) the first ever 2D programming language on a triangular grid, taking many inspirations from existing Fungeoids, but adding the icosahedron as its own interesting twist. There's also two other features regarding control flow, which are comparably rare among 2D languages: the boundaries of the grid don't wrap around (or terminate the program), but instead the IP reflects off them. I had already used this idea for Alice's Ordinal mode, but it was part of Wumpus's design long before I thought of Alice. The other feature is a strafing move, which lets you move the IP orthogonally to its current direction, to sidestep onto the next or previous line. The way this interacts with the triangular grid is quite interesting, I think.

Of course, the name is a reference to the classic game [Hunt the Wumpus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunt_the_Wumpus), which uses an icosahedral map for its dungeon. The game is also a significant part of Fungeoid history.

As a side note, this is the first language since Labyrinth and Hexagony (my first two) which I managed to implement in just two days. Of course, with the idea having brewed for over two years it's not quite the same (those two went from idea to finished implementation in two or three days), but after the lengthy design processes of my recent languages, this honestly felt quite good.

- [**GitHub repository**](https://github.com/m-ender/wumpus). Includes language specification, reference implementation (Ruby), example programs and issue tracker.
- [**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/#wumpus) (by [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis)) backed by the Ruby interpreter.
- [**Esolangs page**](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Wumpus), essentially a mirror of the README on GitHub.
- [***Hunt the Wumpus* in Wumpus**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155641/8478) because I had to.

Answer (score 4):

## [Alc](https://tio.run/#alchemist)[hem](https://github.com/bforte/alchemist/)[ist](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Alchemist)

I created [several](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48198/bmo) languages, but I think  this one is worth posting here since it's a fun concept:

The idea is inspired by chemical reaction networks which consist of a rule-set encoding certain "chemical reactions", eg:

```bash
H + 2O -> H2O
```

A program is just a set of such rules, however there might be rules where their inputs overlap, for example:

```bash
Alice -> Bob
Alice -> Charlie
```

Well, here's where the fun/pain begins: The program has an internal state - called the *universe* - which counts how many atoms of which type there are. At every iteration a uniformly at random rule is picked from all the ones which are applicable (you can change the probabilities by copying the rule).

To bootstrap the whole process the program starts off with one `_`-atom and from there your world starts evolving.

#### Input/Output

There are three types of special atoms which when they would be added to the universe do some I/O instead:

```bash
In_some_name:      Read number from stdin and add that many "some_name"-atoms
Out_some_name:     Output the number of "some_name"-atoms
Out_"some string": Output the string "some string"
```

### Examples

```bash
_ -> Out_"Hello, Alchemist!"
```

Prints `Hello, Alchemist!` to *stdout*: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xJzkjNzSwu@f8/XkHXTsG/tCReySM1JydfR8ERJqeo9P8/AA)

---

```bash
_ -> In_x + In_x + Out_x
```

Reads two integers from *stdin* and outputs their sum: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xJzkjNzSwu@f8/XkHXTsEzL75CQRtG@ZeWxFf8/29kyGVhAAA)

---

Here's how deterministic control-flow can be implemented, ie. use special atoms to store state:

```bash
# Read two integers & add "compare_AB"-atom
_ -> In_A + In_B + compare_AB

# If there is a "compare_AB"-atom:
compare_AB + A + B -> compare_AB   # remove an atom of A and B

# Once there are no more atoms of A or B, we know ..
compare_AB + 0A + 0B -> Out_"eq"   # .. if none of both are left: they're equal
compare_AB + 0A +  B -> not_equal  # .. if only B is left B > A
compare_AB +  A + 0B -> not_equal  # .. if only A is left A > B

# Do something when they're unequal
not_equal -> Out_"neq"
```

Reads two integers and compares them: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDBboNADETvfMUIpPbQBkVRTjlEAvWSU6T@ANqCCSis3cBSlK@nXmhDo7an3fXOvLFtmrwiW3duHCO8kingBkHNjk7UdniAKQqEudh301KWpOHKOLFBhtUeB84SPPkj1WPRBEGEQwlXUUuoO5jfgF2wVNTrMalH/qgCEVqy8kEwDG@ClKo0XGCKOHJOXyFqAQus@Lsqu1kqLdJnDIQzy4A4vg9d@9T1FHvsXRbSJZxC4xh1qTgmT3kTV038hkq383nXR33RpTfNH7x5DBaXTYqFJ9xc9VPX4UF62yO592Pp5z9/cvMn6p@28CLoxJKraj5hqIhvLfY8N7nAvifVj3Act5tgu/kE)

Answer (score 4):

## [Trilangle](https://github.com/bbrk24/Trilangle)

Trilangle is a 2-D esolang that I made in February 2023. Though not designed as a golflang, it ends up being fairly competitive in certain challenges.

It was originally inspired by Hexagony, though it came to be rather different. The biggest differences include:

- Though the code grid is still hexagonal, its bounding box is triangular.
- The memory model is a stack rather than a grid.
- Certain letters and numbers are operations, expanding the instruction set but necessitating a separate "push" instruction.
- When the IP walks off the edge of the code grid, it continues on the row or diagonal to its left, rather than on the opposite side of the grid.
- Instead of bigints, the program operates on 24-bit integers.

The fact that it's a stack, and you can only modify the top of the stack, made Turing completeness difficult. See [the old proof of TC'ness](https://github.com/bbrk24/Trilangle/blob/1b54ffdde92fb162108869b7a089e669c184cecf/turing_completeness.md) from Trilangle 1.0. The modern version looks rather different, since the threading operator means you can have multiple stacks. Though I haven't needed this for code golf yet, I use this in [my implementation of selection sort](https://github.com/bbrk24/miscellany/blob/master/sortingAlgorithm.trg) (colorized version [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/and34.png)).

String processing is a downright pain, though that's not entirely unintentional. Hello, World ends up being a somewhat longer program:

```
        "
       H o
      o " !
     " o ( o
    e o o o l
   o " " " o "
  " , W r " ! 3
 l o o o d o : o
o " " " o ' ( @ .
```

Or, condensed (newlines, spaces, and trailing NOPs removed):

```
"Hoo"!"o(oeooolo"""o"",Wr"!3looodo:oo"""o'(@
```

To help me design and debug these programs, I've invented an assembly-like syntax for these programs. It represents 2D branches and loops with `BNG` (branch if negative) and `JMP` (jump) instructions. For example, the (2-D) source code and assembly for cat are as follows:

```
    #
   @ .
  . L \
 v i o .
. _ \ , .
```

```
0:  NOP
1:  NOP
2:  NOP
3:  NOP
4:  GTC
5:  BNG 12
6:  NOP
7:  PTC
8:  NOP
9:  POP
10: NOP
11: JMP 2
12: EXT
```

Of course, this contains a lot of extraneous NOPs. Any instruction that unconditionally redirects the IP is represented with `NOP` by the disassembler, so there's a flag to hide NOPs (`-n` on the CLI; always on in [the online interpreter](https://bbrk24.github.io/Trilangle/)). With that flag set, the assembly just becomes:

```
4:  GTC
5:  BNG 12
7:  PTC
9:  POP
11: JMP 2
12: EXT
```

`GTC` and `PTC` stand for "getchar" and "putchar" respectively -- though they behave more like C's `getwchar` and `putwchar`, using UTF-32.

For the most part, the instruction set contains a lot of what you'd expect for an integer-only stack-based language -- arithmetic, bitwise operations, branch on sign, and I/O -- but it also contains a few interesting choices. For example, `T` (get current time) uses a unit of 1/97 second*, so that the full day spans from 0 at midnight to 0x7fffff right before midnight. The threading operator is also [heavily overloaded](https://github.com/bbrk24/Trilangle#threading).

Finally, just for fun: here's a program that doesn't halt on weekends.

```
    <
   ' D
  ' - 2
 2 ' % 7
@ > { # -
```

*More accurately, there are 97.0903588 time units to the second.

Answer (score 3):

In my questions [Simulate a Minsky Register Machine (I)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1864/194) and [Simulate a Minsky Register Machine (II)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3897/194) I define essentially two versions of a programming language which is just a textual representation of MRMs. The intention was already to build towards version (III), which would add macros with unification. I'm also thinking about adding some additional I/O and arithmetic operations.

Comment: Do it!    &nbsp;    &nbsp;

Answer (score 3):

## [PyMin](https://github.com/daHugLenny/PyMin)

This is a language created by me.

It's a lazy one (something like [Dogescript](https://dogescript.com/)?), because pretty much the entire language is Python, except there are specific two bytes chars that get replaced by something, and then executed as normal Python.

---

#### Examples:

**Hello, World!**

```
»Ħ
```

or if you want the `W` to be lowercase:

```
»ħ
```

**FizzBuzz (v0.1)**

```
¥i¦ȑ101):
 s¨
 ¿i%3ʭ0:sϯƒ
 ¿i%5ʭ0:sϯɓ
 ¿sɵ:»s
 Ə»i
```

I added more stuff into the language, so in `v0.5` it can be shortened to:

```
ŒʘƆ
 s¨
 ¿i%3ǆ:sϯƒ
 ¿i%5ǆ:sϯɓ
 ¿sɵ:»s
 Ə»i
```

**Degrees to radians**

```
»ȹ¬)
```

**Celsius to fahrenheint**

```
»Ɋ¬)
```

**Primality check**

```
»Գ¬)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Karaoke

Karaoke is a scripting language created by me for internal use at a company I was working for in November 2013 (if you don't mind, I would avoid putting the name of the company here). I coordinated its development until September 2016 when I left the company.

The interpreter is not open-source, unfortunately, and not available to the general public, the company is using it for internal testing of their algorithms. There is no reference to the language on the company web site, and the name is not referenced anywhere, so I am sorry, I can't provide any evidence of doing it.

The syntax is based on Javascript, but with some Ruby in it. It's loosely object-oriented, but all available classes are part of the standard library, and the user can not define new classes in the language itself. The user can however define new functions.

The interpreter was built starting from a lex file, and was a simple one-pass scanner in the first versions, then I added a parser written in yacc in order to implement the object system and the control structures.

The features I liked particularly:

- Default variable: the last result is stored into the default variable "_" which is used as an input value to the next function call.
- Shortcuts: every object has a standard method which can be called using the bracket operator. So if `s` was an `outputstream` object and the default method of the `outputstream` class was `println` you could just call `s("Hello World")`. Method names could be abbreviated like in goruby.
- Dynamic reference: this was, I think, the only feature of the language I did not directly steal from another existing language (but was of course inspired by similar features). You could define a value as a dynamic reference by adding a '&' in front of it. So if `x=5; y=6; a=x+y` and `b=&x+y`, then a would always be 11, but the value of b would change dynamically when you cnahged the value of x or y.

And then of course a lot of domain-specific features like input processing, output in some particular format, and interface to the library we wanted to test... It started like a fun experiment but at the end it was just another COBOL.

Answer (score 3):

## [Chip](https://github.com/Phlarx/chip)

Chip is an esoteric language designed by me, Phlarx. It is my first language, and I started designing this in December 2016. It can be found on [Try It Online](https://tio.run/nexus/chip), too.

This language is inspired by integrated circuits and digital logic, and as such, it is a 2.5D language that somewhat resembles circuitry. (I say 2.5D because Chip circuits can be layered atop one another, so it resides somewhere between 2D and 3D).

Since Chip deals with digital logic, it looks at individual bits for each operation, however, it is capable of reading eight bits of input (usually called a byte or octet) and writing eight bits of output on each cycle.

Chip currently has a single stack or a single queue, and has limited ability to jump back to earlier input. There are plans to further enhance its abilities in these areas, such as a second queue/stack, or addressable memory instead.

This language is still a work in progress. You can check out the rough todo list, as well as some more examples at the [github page](https://github.com/Phlarx/chip).

#### Example 1

Take the value of the three high bits of input, and output them as an ASCII numeral.

```
Fa Gb Hc e*f
```

Input `Chip™` becomes `2333745`.

#### Example 2

Print 1 if consecutive bytes are equal, 0 otherwise.

```
AZ BZ CZ DZ EZ FZ GZ HZ   e*Z~S
`}.`}.`}.`}.`}.`}.`}.`}.   f
  `--^--^--^--^--^--^--^~a
```

Input `Hello PPCG` produces `001000100`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg)

I figured I might as well get around to writing up an answer to this question to show people a side of Keg they probably haven't seen before.

### The Backstory

Let’s start off real simple. Keg is made by me, Lyxal, although on GitHub and esolangs, I'm called JonoCode9374.

Anyhow, Keg was the second esolang I've ever made, with my first being a Minecraft based fungoid language. It's also the first golfing language I've ever made.

Back in 2018 when I was still new to esolangs, I was reading and learning about the ><> language. I absolutely loved the 2d layout as well as the simple stack manipulation abilities it contained. It was ><> that introduced me to stacks. And it was ><> that would influence the creation of Keg.

Starting from scratch, I didn't really know what to include in a golfing language. But I did know that I wanted to make the instruction set completely ascii, as I (at the time) found Unicode languages just too hard to understand (boy, how that's gone out the window!).

Touching on that point a bit more, I've had a kind of mindset of "if you don't understand it, make your own". Now, I know that people would say that such a perspective of life is ineffective, as one can't just create complex systems if they don't understand it. And I agree, generally I don't follow this way of thinking. But when it comes to something manageable like golfing language design, I believe it's fair game.

Also, I feel like I should mention I created Keg as a sort of protest against the big and established languages that seemed to always win... I kinda solved the issue of golfing langs sucking all the fun out of CGCC for myself.

Working my way through the process of language creation, I eventually finished the original interpreter, and, on the 5th of November, I created the GitHub repo for Keg.

After doing so, I wrote a few answers here on CGCC and, after a few weeks of inactivity, I decided I'd move on from Keg.

Then, around 5 months later, I decided I would browse through esolangs.org to see what languages there were. Looking through the recent edits, I saw something that would drive the second phase of Keg development: [Teg](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Teg).

At first, I was kind of offended, as it seemed like a personal attack on the little language I
had created. Wanting to prove whoever had created this page wrong that they had created something better than Keg, I started plotting out a brick ton of operators to add.

But then I learned that A__ (I'm on mobile, using an external markdown editor, whaddya expect?) was actually friendly and that they were just mucking around (I think), I was a bit more relaxed about Keg development. (I now view Teg as a kind of compliment ;p)

Needless to say, after ~2 months of extensive planning, ~30 pieces of paper with sketches of what aspects might look like, I finally started developing Keg's first major expansion.

Now, this expansion contained features such as strings, integer scanning, new register commands and variables. But the interpreter I had wasn't suited for such new things. So I had to rewrite everything. It was at this point I made Keg transpiled… one of the best decisions I've made in regards to Keg.

Later on, it came time to deal with finer aspects of the expansion. Such an example of this was string compression. Now, here's the thing... this was at a time when I thought all characters were a single byte each. Ha, what a silly idea. I was thinking of having a 400k word dictionary making good usage of the ~100k Unicode characters. But then I learned about byte counts. So that's why there's only 60k words in the dictionary.

Why am I telling you all this? Well, I figured I would explain a little bit of the behind the scenes information about Keg. It may be fragmented, but it's the best I can do at the moment.

### Main Features

*The following is 'borrowed' from the esolangs page... Which I just happened to write ;P*

The main inspiration for Keg comes from a want of an esolang where only symbols count as commands and everything else is pushed onto the stack as a literal. This is why there are only 12 functions, 7 ‘keywords’ and 8 operators. As such, this system allows for shorter programs where strings are involved (*uncompressed* strings in Keg are usually 1-2 bytes shorter than their counterparts in other languages).

Another design feature of Keg is the look of if statements, for loops and while loops. These structures take on the form of:

```
B...B
```

Where B is any of the three brackets (`(`/`)`, `[`/`]` or `{`/`}`) and `...` is any section of Keg code.

#### Some Basics

Most tutorials show how to print the string `Hello, World!`, so that’s what this tutorial will do as well. Here is a simple 21 byte program to achieve the goal.

```
Hello\, World\!^(!|,)

Hello # Push the characters "H", "e", "l", "l" and "o" to the stack
\,    # Escape the "," and push it to the stack
World # Push the characters "W", "o", "r", "l" and "d" to the stack
\!    # Escape the "!" and push it to the stack ^ #Reverse the stack
(!|   # Start a for loop and set the count to the length of the stack
  ,   # Print the last item on the stack as a character
)
```

In the above example, 6 new functions and keywords are introduced:

- `\` : Escapes the next command, and instead pushes it as a string (pushes its ASCII value)
- `,` : Prints the last item on the stack as a character
- `!` : Pushes the length of the stack onto the stack
- `^` : Reverses the stack
- `(...)` : The for loop structure
- `|` : Used in structures to switch from one branch to the other.

One of the most important parts of Keg is the stack, which is where all operations are performed. A stack is a type of container (or list) where the last item in the container is the first item to be operated on (LIFO – Last In First Out). In the following examples, the stack will be investigated.

```
3 # [3]
4 # [3, 4]
+ # [7]
```

In the above example, the numbers 3 and 4 are pushed onto the stack, and are then added using the `+` operator. The way it works is that the `+` pops what will be called \$x\$ and \$y\$ off the stack (the first and second last item) and pushes \$y + x\$ back onto the stack. Note that the order of \$x\$ and \$y\$ are important when using the `-` and `\` operators, as \$x - y\$ doesn’t equal \$y - x\$ most of the time (as is the same with \$x \div y\$ and \$y \div x\$). This can be seen in the following example:

```
34-. # Outputs -1
43-. # Outputs 1 
34/. # Outputs 0.75 
43/. # Outputs 1.333333333333
```

Note that the `.` function prints the last item on the stack as an integer.

Keg has two output functions and one input function. When taking input from the user, the next line from the Standard Input and push the ASCII value of each character onto the stack. It will then push -1 onto the stack to signify the end of input (input as integers will be coming in a later version of Keg). Input is taken using the ? command, as shown in the example program:

```
?(!|,) 
# > Example text 
# Example text
```

The two output functions (`.` – Print as integer and `,` – Print as string) have already been detailed in other sections

### Links

- [Github](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg)
- [Try it Online](https://tio.run/#keg)
- [Esolangs](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Keg)

Comment: On GitHub you’re called lyxal.

Answer (score 3):

## MAWP

MAWP was created by me, Dion, in May 2020. My main goal was to create a language that was shorter than non-golfing languages while still being simple to use and being able to answer a wide range of questions without major difficulty. The only letters used are `M`, `A`, `W` and `P`. With this in mind, I wanted to have quite a number of builtins while not using any other letters and still having characters that are accessible on a standard keyboard.

The only interpreter easily accessible by everyone is [this](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v1.1) one, also written by me. It also has an [esolangs page](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP).

## Some example programs

### Numbers by position:

```
[![~!:~1A]%!9A?.%1M]
```

Explanation:

```
[      start of loop
!      duplicates top of stack
[      start of loop
~!:~   prints bottom stack value
1A     subtracts 1
]      end of loop
%      removes top of stack (0 from the counter in the previous loop)
!9A    diffeence between top value and 9
?.     if top 0, then terminate program
%      removes top value
1M     adds 1 to top value
]      end of loop
```

### Print the alphabet:

```
[!43W8WM;1M!93WA?.%]
```

Explanation:

```
[        start of loop
!        duplicate top of stack
43W8W    push 96 to stack (4*3*8)
M        add 96 to number below
;        output top of stack as ASCII char
1M       add 1 to top of stack
!        duplicate top of stack
93W      push 27 to stack (9*3)
A        Difference of top two stack values
?.       is equal to zero, then terminate program
%        pop top of stack
]        end of loop
```

### FizzBuzz:

Printing long strings is the biggest downside of MAWP, since you need to generate the ASCII code for each character with basic operations and numbers from 0 to 9.

```
[!!3P3WA<75W2W;73W5W;65W2W1M2W;65W2W1M2W;~0~>%!!5P5WA<92M6W;94M9W;65W2W1M2W;65W2W1M2W;~0~>%~{~!:~}~!554WWA?.%1M25W;~(%)]
```

```
[                                              Start loop
!!3P3WA                                        Is divisible by 3? (Homemade modulo 
                                               function)
<                                              If top of stack is not 0 (number is
                                               not divisible), then jump to its >
75W2W;73W5W;65W2W1M2W;65W2W1M2W;               Print 'Fizz'
~0~                                            Add 0 to the bottom of stack by 
                                               double reversing
>                                              End conditional
%                                              Remove modulo function result
!!5P5WA<92M6W;94M9W;65W2W1M2W;65W2W1M2W;~0~>%  Do the same for 'Buzz'
~                                              Reverse stack
{                                              If there are no 0 on the top of 
                                               stack (not 'Fizz' nor 'Buzz' was
                                               printed), 
~!:~                                           then print the current number
}~                                             End conditional and reverse stack
!554WWA?.%                                     If the number is 100, then terminate
                                               program
1M25W;                                         Print newline
~(%)                                           Remove all 0 from bottom of stack
]                                              End of loop
```

Comment: I thought that `MAWP` primarily uses English letters. To my surprise it actually uses a lot of symbols...

Answer (score 3):

### [minigolf](https://github.com/jfioasd/minigolf)

An esolang created by me (jfioasd) that is neither like a golflang nor like a tarpit esolang.

Originally, it was going to be a golfing language with an octal encoding. While packing as many useful commands as possible, I made the language extremely minimalistic.

Later, I found that it's too hard to program in (because octal doesn't let you pack a lot of useful builtins and constants inside it that makes golfing easier) so I decided to turn it into an esolang.

minigolf is neither competitive as a golflang nor as tiny as a tarpit, rather somewhere between these two. It has high-level builtins (such as map and flatten) that make a lot of things convenient, but programs written in minigolf can actually be quite long.

For the naming, consider it as a portmanteau of 'mini' (as in [Mini-flak](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Mini-Flak)) and 'golf'(as in [mathgolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf)).

Answer (score 3):

## Morsecco

*Morsecco* is a minimalistic, but mighty programming language using **morse c**ode for **co**ding (hence the sparkling name). You need only a dot for the short beep, a stroke (dash or slash) for the long beep and a whitespace for the break between letters. This already makes it the coolest coding feeling ever, because on most keyboards you can put your right thumb on space key, two other fingers on dot and stroke key and start coding, hardly moving your hand and leaving the left hand free for your beer or pizza.

And if you think that this must feel great, just wait until you realise that it doesn't take long until you can actually create complex and even useful software that way! It's not just one more of that esoteric languages, where it's hard to solve even a simple task. If you know some morse codes, a little forth and are a type safety anarchist, you can almost start. Otherwise read the [tutorial](https://github.com/Philipp-Sasse/morsecco/blob/main/Morsecco%20tutorial.pdf).

- only **one** data type: a cell (can be text, numbers, addresses, executable code ...)
- only **two** memory locations: a stack and an addressable storage
- only **three** significant characters: dot, dash and space
- only seventeen commands by now (including help and debug), but extremely easy to expand
- includes an interactive shell that can be mixed with scripts
- file writing and reading, WWW access, random numbers, numeric conversion even with float base
- great golfing fun, because there are so many ways to do things including self-modifying code
- `git clone https://github.com/Philipp-Sasse/morsecco.git`
- or `pip install morsecco`

Just to give you a tiny impression, the following code defines a new command `-.` that adds 5 to a number, and demonstrates it by putting 3 on the stack, call the new command and output the result 8:

```
morsecco '.   . -.- .-  . -. .-- . -- -. ---'
-...
```

Defining the command only takes a couple of characters in a language with only three symbols! Here comes an explanation (the highlighted `C`apitals refer to morse codes: `.` is the morse code for `E` and for the morsecco command `E`nter. Numbers are coded in binary, so 8 is `1000`, translating to `-...`):

- `. -.- .-` is `E`nter (`.`) 5 (`-.-`) on the stack and `A`dd (`.-`)
- the `E`nter command at the beginning puts this command (everything between the triple and the double space) on the stack
- `. -. .--` `E`nters the address `-.`, to where we `W`rite the command (you could also Read it there to use it like a variable)
- `. -- -.` `E`nters 3 (`--`) and calls the new command (yes: as soon as you write to an address, you can use this address like a command to execute it!)
- `---` Output the top of the stack

Feedback and support is highly welcome.

Answer (score 2):

## MOVr

MOVr is a self-modifying language of mine in which everything is a MOV instruction (and simultaneously data.) However, the 2^24 64-bit words of addressable data also include the IP (at 0xfffffe) and an IO port (at 0xfffffd.) Instructions take the following (binary) format:

```
 01 23 456789 ABCDEF
|dl|sl|-dest-|-src--|
```

`dl` and `sl` are the destination and source levels, which tell how many times each must be dereferenced (mod 2^24.) If `dl` is 0, then the instruction acts as a no-op. If the IP goes past 0xffffff, the program terminates. Writes to and reads from the IO print and input Unicode characters. Data not filled by the program is assumed to be zeroed. This means that if you don't jump to the exit (with 0x0100fffffeffffff), then your code will have to travel through all the 2^24 instructions (and possibly wreak havoc while passing through the IP and IO.) Sadly, a working interpreter is not available at this time.

Answer (score 2):

### [Glava](https://github.com/GamrCorps/Java-Golf)

I, GamrCorps, made Glava in January 2016. It is still a MAJOR work-in-progress, but it is still very useful. Click the link above to view the docs and download the interpreter (written in Java).

Glava is a Java dialect focused on code golf. Many of the common keywords and phrases can be shortened down two around two characters each. It also sports an autocomplete feature, where you can omit the `}`s, `]`s, `)`s, and `"`s at the end of your code and it will automatically put them in.

Another neat feature is what I call MCRP (Main Class Recognition and Placement). Simply put, if you do not have a class anywhere in the file, the interpreter will put one there for you! Also, a few common import statements will automatically be placed in with the same process (`java.utils.*`, `java.lang.*`, etc.)!

The interpreter SHOULD work in any Java version (I believe past 6), because it compiles the Glava programs into your native Java version.

Answer (score 2):

## [IPOS](https://github.com/DenkerAffe/IPOS)

#### Made by me, DenkerAffe

IPOS (short for *I process only strings*) is a stack-based golfing language made for complex string processing. It will have a huge amount of string manipulation builtins, so it will probably (hopefully) win every challenge which is about transforming an input string into an output string.

I finished the basic core recently, now it is only about implementing builtins. A list of all planned (not-complete) and already implemented commands can be found [here](https://github.com/DenkerAffe/IPOS/wiki/Commands).

The input to an IPOS program is placed on the stack automatically. At the end of the program all stack items are converted to strings and get joined into one string which then get printed.

### Example programs

**Hello World**

```
"Hello World!
```

**Split input on dots, reverse each substring and join all substring on dots**

```
'.!r%
```

**Explanation**

```
       Implicit: place input string on the stack (C)
'.     Push a dot to the stack (B)
!r     Push the reverse command to the stack (A)
%      Split C on B, apply A to every part and join the result on B
       Implicit: Output the stack contents
```

**Swap case of every character in the input randomly**

```
E!s?
```

**Explanation**

```
       Implicit: place input string on the stack (C)
E      Push an empty string to the stack (B)
!k     Push the swapcase command to the stack (A)
?      Split C on B (=split into characters), apply A to every part and join the result on B
       Implicit: output the stack contents
```

Comment: Do you mean "I process only strings", not "I progress only strings"?

Comment: @EasterlyIrk I do. Thanks for spotting!

Answer (score 2):

## Logicode

[Github repo here.](https://github.com/LogicodeLang/Logicode)

Logicode was created by me, Qwerp-Derp, on August 31, 2016. It's basically a coded version of Logisim.

The language consists of three built-in logic gates, `AND`, `OR` and `NOT` (which are represented as `&`, `|` and `!` respectively), and that's basically it. You do the rest.

You can make:

- circuits (which are basically functions)

  - these only take strings of `0` and `1` as input and output strings of `0` and `1` as output.
- variables
- conditionals

You can also use stuff like:

- input/output
- random ints
- comments
- reversing strings

### Github stuffs

If anyone can improve the code, go ahead and post a pull request!

If you have any issues, please put it in "Issues".

Answer (score 2):

## [Bean](https://github.com/patrickroberts/bean)

Bean is an esoteric byte-encoded code-golfing language derived from JavaScript, and was created by me, Patrick Roberts, in January 2017.

The inspiration behind Bean was one of frustration. I typically submit answers in JavaScript (ES6), and was aware of its shortcomings in verbosity, such as `String.fromCharCode(...)`. I thought it would be cool to write a language where every global and standard identifier (like `String` and `fromCharCode` respectively) could be represented by single bytes in a byte-encoded language, and thus JavaScript's code-golfing hero, Bean, was born.

The backend uses [babylon](https://github.com/babel/babylon) to convert any JavaScript source code omitting comments, directives (`use strict`), decorators (`@readonly`), and a few other AST nodes that were exclusive to `module` syntax (`export default`, for example), and traverses the constructed AST depth-first, encoding each node in 1 or 2 bytes, and then recursing to encode the child nodes sequentially.

Some of the features that make Bean differ from JavaScript is the advantage of implicit input and output. For example, the following JavaScript compiles to a valid Bean program that adds two integers and outputs the sum:

JavaScript:

```
A+B
```

Bean Hexdump (7 bytes):

```
00000000 26 4c a0 43 8b 20 44
00000007
```

[The best valid JavaScript answer for this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84281/42091), in comparison, is 9 bytes. You can check [the demo for this Bean program here](https://patrickroberts.github.io/bean/#h=JkygQ4sgRA==&i=Mwo0).

The implicit input is read line-by-line, and string literals of each line are stored in the lowercase identifiers `a-z` (then `aa`, `ab`, `ac`...) while successful JSON-parsed lines are stored in `A-Z` (then `AA`, `AB`, `AC`...). In addition, the array of all string literals is stored in `_` while the sparse array of successful JSON-parsed lines is stored in `$`. To make this clearer, consider the following input:

```
5
hello
"hello"
{"hello": "world"}
[hello]
[5, "hello"]
```

The implicit input would be populated as follows:

```
var a = "5",
    b = "hello",
    c = "\"hello\"",
    d = "{\"hello\": \"world\"}",
    e = "[hello]",
    f = "[5, \"hello\"]",
    A = 5,
    C = "hello",
    D = {"hello": "world"},
    F = [5, "hello"],
    _ = [
      "5",
      "hello",
      "\"hello\"",
      "{\"hello\": \"world\"}",
      "[hello]",
      "[5, \"hello\"]"
    ],
    $ = [5, , "hello", {"hello": "world"}, , [5, "hello"]];
```

Attempting to reference `B` or `E` would throw an error, and `$[1]` and `$[4]` would return `undefined`, and would not be iterated over with `.map()` or `.forEach()`.

I currently don't have any documentation, as I've just explained every way in which Bean differs from JavaScript, but feel free to open an issue on [github](https://github.com/patrickroberts/bean) if you feel that documenting the byte code is necessary. Bean is also available on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bean-js), <s>but the implicit input and output only works on the online interpreter for now. I'll internalize that in a later update.</s> The node.js implementation now includes a hook for implicit input and output via `bean.program()`. See [README](https://github.com/patrickroberts/bean) for usage.

[The interpreter](https://patrickroberts.github.io/bean/#h=JkygQ4sgRA==&i=Mwo0) accepts any arbitrary JavaScript and automatically converts it to a hexdump for you. Alternatively, you can copy/paste any valid hexdump and it will reconstruct the equivalent JavaScript for you.

One tip I can offer is to attempt to use "standard" identifiers as much as possible, even in your strings, regular expressions, and template strings, since all literals expand to identifiers, and those that are not stored in the configuration file must be appended to the end of the byte code.

At the very least, repeated use of the same non-standard identifiers are reduced to referencing the same subarray of bytes at the end of the byte code, so don't bother storing `"my really long necessary string"` to a variable, because that will waste 3 bytes:

```
// 41 bytes

(s="my really long necessary string")===s

// 43 bytes

00000000 26 4c cd a0 6f 80 23 81 01 82 20 6f ed f9 a0 f2  &LÍ o.#... oíù ò
00000010 e5 e1 ec ec f9 a0 ec ef ee e7 a0 ee e5 e3 e5 f3  åáììù ìïîç îåãåó
00000020 f3 e1 f2 f9 a0 f3 f4 f2 e9 ee 67                 óáòù óôòéîg
0000002b

// vs...

// 69 bytes

"my really long necessary string"==="my really long necessary string"

// 40 bytes

00000000 26 4c a3 81 01 82 23 81 01 ed f9 a0 f2 e5 e1 ec  &L£...#..íù òåáì
00000010 ec f9 a0 ec ef ee e7 a0 ee e5 e3 e5 f3 f3 e1 f2  ìù ìïîç îåãåóóáò
00000020 f9 a0 f3 f4 f2 e9 ee 67                          ù óôòéîg
00000028
```

Comment: Heh, I too created [a language](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/) out of frustration with `String.fromCharCode`, as did [Downgoat](https://github.com/vihanb/TeaScript) :-)

Answer (score 2):

## [CGL (CGL Golfing Language)](https://codepen.io/programmer5000/pen/zwYrVd)

CGL was created two days ago (4/11/17) by me. It uses a stack concept like other languages, but unlike other languages there are multiple stacks that you manipulate instead of one. You start on the `0`th stack, which is empty by default. The `-1`th stack contains each input argument. All other stacks (integers) can be used for anything. Most operators either push something to the stack based on something already on the stack or perform an operation on all elements of the current stack.

- [Here is the interpreter](https://codepen.io/programmer5000/pen/zwYrVd) (docs coming soon)

Answer (score 2):

## [GolfeMatics](https://github.com/NeilAllavarpu/GolfeMatics)

GolfeMatics is a language developed by me, and I am designing it to be focused on math-related problems. The only types in the language are integers, decimals, and soon will also include lists. Booleans are false if they are equal to 0, true otherwise. No one needs strings, so I didn't add them. In fact, the only string-related command is `A`, which modulo's the current number by 128 and prints out the corresponding ASCII character. To see how ridiculous this makes this at programs involving strings, look at the [Hello, World!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128740/69401)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pepe](https://github.com/Soaku/Pepe)

Programming language inspired by an old meme, Pepe.

Uses two stacks and uses only 4 characters: `reRE`.

Every command in it begins with R/r, followed by a certain amount of E/e, ex. `REEE`. The R/r define on which stack the command has to work on (1st or 2nd), while E/e define the command used. Both amount of letters and their case matters. [List of commands is available on GitHub](https://github.com/Soaku/Pepe/blob/master/commands.md).

### Links:

- [GitHub](https://github.com/Soaku/Pepe)
- [Online interpreter](https://soaku.github.io/Pepe/)
- [List of commands](https://github.com/Soaku/Pepe/blob/master/commands.md)
- [Submissions in Pepe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=Pepe)

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: who bulit?????????

Answer (score 2):

## [2DFuck](https://gitlab.com/TheWastl/2DFuck)

2DFuck is a very simple language created by me. It is inspired by brainfuck,
but operates on a 2-dimensional matrix of bits instead of a tape of bytes.
And it has an accumulator. The code is **not** 2D, only the memory.

It does also have the `l` built-in to run Conway's Game of Life on the memory,
though I haven't written any programs using this so far.

Programming is, in my opinion, a bit easier than in brainfuck, because of the
2D memory and the accumulator.

Finally, a piece of code (a cat program):

```
!x>>>>>>>>vxvx[^^r![<r!]v![,x>r!]^![<r!]vr![>r!]vr![^^r![<r!]vv![^r.x>vr!]<]r!]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYqxCoAgEIb3nuLcw6E53NvbRCHKSLIMNb23txuEjp@7@z@@Ydvf9ayVoWiTMaPUOjA5BqYykz0KenTrxEW7v0SWDhwFUTUqWrXOh41AWW4wuFyPM7ybEmzeEHPRQ/HhhGLTAdfrkiUBnL1N5B8)

[Here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164346/78123) is an explanation.

**+++ [GitLab repository](https://gitlab.com/TheWastl/2DFuck)
+++ [Online interpreter](https://tio.run/#2dfuck)
+++**

Answer (score 2):

## Runic

This language was created by me, Draco18s on Sep 18, 2018.

- [Documentation](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments)
- [Interpreter](https://tio.run/#runic)

The idea had been floating around in my head for a while, not actually as a programming language, but as a concept for a while. Mostly due to reading lit RPG books like [Emerilia](https://www.goodreads.com/series/198985-emerilia). I wanted some way to write in-game code that would be attached to an item or object that would act as a magical enchantment.

September 18th I pretty much sat down and started working out a basic set of instructions and framework for the language and the initial interpreter just to see if I could get something that worked. I took a lot of inspiration from [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), as I'd worked with it a bit in the weeks prior, and wanting something a little more powerful. After a couple of hours I had a small, but functional language.

But it was really on Dec 16, 2018 when I added support for Unicode Combining characters that would modify various instructions in a variety of ways, such as `a͕` would executes the `a` command (push 10) normally before altering the IP's direction to point right (overriding whatever direction it was facing). While combining characters will only combine visually with a certain subset of symbols (i.e. `"͕` ) the interpreter doesn't care. While certain modifiers are often not competitive in code golf (due to the 2 or 3 byte cost for each one), they do unlock the ability to perform otherwise complex or impossible operations (such as rotating a string or swapping substacks).

The other main feature of Runic is that it supports an arbitrary number of simultaneously executed instruction pointers that can merge (if in the same cell and facing the same direction) and split (with one of four commands). Each instruction pointer has a current "mana" value, where some instructions cost mana (namely reflection, eval, sorting, substacks, and splitting) and if an IP ever runs out of mana it fizzles out of existence. Each IP's own stack is also size limited by its current mana, making large data sets almost impossible to work with. The idea being that magic, being magic, requires more energy to do Big Things.

I'd definitely like to rebuild the language from the ground up to do more, have each given instruction handle a wider range of input types (some instructions only operate on, say, strings but currently does nothing if it gets a pair of integers, but would do *something* instead that's currently handled by an instruction that currently operates on integers and not strings), and possibly have a custom code page (for extra golfiness). But it isn't high on my todo list.

And yes, I did eventually get around to implementing some of the more game-y features [in Minecraft](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/272860530505547776/536721740437520404/clank.gif) (just an example of an effect that spawns a particle to 'charge up' even if the final effect is just to print some text in chat, but it could spawn blocks too).

Answer (score 2):

### [Flip](https://github.com/jfioasd/Flip)

A 1D language inspired by [Backhand](https://github.com/GrayJoKing/Backhand/).

It was inspired by the fact that `v` was used [very commonly](https://github.com/jfioasd/esolang-analysis/blob/main/misc/Backhand.txt) in the language, so I started to wonder whether Backhand's IP step of 3 was too big.

It turns out that if you want the IP to be bidirectional, only 2 groups of commands are actually needed: even-indexed characters for forward IP movement, and odd-indexed characters for backwards movement.

`|` is very common in Backhand as well. So I thought of generalizing Backhand's `|` to make it the primary looping structure of the language, while also doing an implicit shifting between the even and odd characters (due to the fact that IP shifting is very common in Backhand). This turned out to be extemely powerful, and also removed the need of `>` and `<`.

Regarding `&`, it came from a need to implement foreach/map/filter/reduce loops in a painless way. I took inspiration from x86's `loop` and used an accumulator to store the count. When used with stack shifting `m`, you could easily implement a lot of higher-order functions with it.

Speaking of program termination, infinite loops are not as common as programs that terminate, so I made the program terminate when the IP goes over the left bound.

However, later I added a ton of builtins to the language (taken from Keg, Factor, Jelly (particularly the `Y` builtin)), and they ended up being quite useless, to be honest. I've used up every ASCII character and there isn't any builtin in there that's substantially useful.

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmoslang](https://github.com/theRealDadsdy/Desmos-Userscript/tree/main/Desmos%20Programming%20Language) and Desmoslang Assembly

Desmoslang is a programming language I created. It is designed to use Desmos's capabilities. It was originally created just to see if I could make a programming language in Desmos, before I realized that it could be a decent golfing language (especially with some more built-ins). I am open to suggestions on what built-ins to add!

Answer (score 1):

## [INXW63CTMNZGS4DU](https://github.com/theksp25/INXW63CTMNZGS4DU)

INXW63CTMNZGS4DU is a imperative/functional 1D golfing language I have created the 16 may 2016.

Example code:

```
→Fλ²$
(F5
```

will print 25.

Normally, a lambda end with a ';', a call with a ')', so the same code can be rewritten like this:

```
→Fλ²$;
(F5)
```

But since it the end of line, it's not needed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Neoscript](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/neoscript)

Neoscript is a language I have created.

Neoscript is a high-level, functional language compiling to JavaScript.

#### Examples:

#### Hello world:

```
console:log("Hello, World!")
```

Comment: Does this language even have an implementation?

Comment: @Fatalize Yes... The generated JavaScript just need to be launched with a special library

Answer (score 1):

### [JLisp](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/jlisp)

JLisp is a Lisp dialect I created the first day of November.

It's a basic Lisp dialect, probably TC and with bad support of scoping.

Hello world:

```
(write-line "Hello, World!")
```

Comment: Does this language still exist? The GitHub link is broken ...

Answer (score 1):

## Triangularity

Triangularity was created on January 5th, 2018 by me, [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder). It is a new esolang, which only has a few commands. Loops are not implemented yet (but that is, hopefully, about to change), so <s>it’s definitely not Turing-Complete</s> (it can evaluate Python :|). In fact, it can only participate in very simple challenges. It’s stack based. Some helpful resources:

- **[Github repository](https://github.com/Mr-Xcoder/Triangularity)** and **[Documentation](https://github.com/Mr-Xcoder/Triangularity/wiki)**.
- If you want help learning it, want to request features, spot bugs or anything else, feel free to ping me (`@Mr.Xcoder`) in its **[dedicated chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71290/a-triangular-strange-esolang)**.
- Thanks to our moderator, Dennis, you can **[Try it online!](https://tio.run/#triangularity)**

#### Fun facts

- A valid Triangularity program must have the character count listed in [OEIS A056220](https://oeis.org/A056220).
- Each Triangularity program must be padded with dots such that the overall shape of the program is rectangular, but the dots themselves must be laid out in nice, right-angled and isosceles triangles. Basic rules:

  - If you have **N** lines of code, each line must consist of **2N - 1** characters.
  - The **K**th line, counting from the bottom, must be padded with **K - 1** dots on each side.
- Any character that is not a command is ignored (unless we’re talking about the newlines and the dots that make up for the padding).

Answer (score 1):

## [17](https://github.com/RaspPiTor/17)

17 is a stack based language that has a bit of a focus on the number 17, for example it uses base 17 and whenever it tries to pop off an empty stack it returns 17.
It has blocks of code defined as < base-17 number > {< code >}. It starts at block 777 and then goes to whichever the block in memory location 0.

Examples:

Hello world:

```
777 {
    44 $ 5g $ 66 : : $ $ 69 : $ 1f $ 52 $ $ 6c $ $ 5f $ 1g $ a $ 0 @
}
```

Count down from 100 to 1(inclusive):

```
0 {
2 #
1 -
:
2 @
2 <
0 @
2 # $$
a $
}


777 {
5g 2 @
0 1 @
0 0 @
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Reflections](https://gitlab.com/TheWastl/Reflections#reflections)

Reflections is a 2D Language. A typical program (Fibonacci):

```
     \
/*\   /# (0:0\
* 0  *\_ (0\/ :(0\
  \       v/#@/_ /
\  (1/   1)0)*
          : \\/
          \(1/
```

[Here](http://thewastl.gitlab.io/Reflections/reflections.html##ICAgICBcCi8qXCAgIC8jICgwOjBcCiogMCAgKlxfICgwXC8gOigwXAogIFwgICAgICAgdi8jQC9fIC8KXCAgKDEvICAgMSkwKSoKICAgICAgICAgIDogXFwvCiAgICAgICAgICBcKDEv/zH/MP8w/w==) is the online interpreter to test it.

The most special thing is that you need to go to certain positions in the
coordinate system to perform very simple actions (e.g. add, push numbers).
It has 11 stacks, and you can move around values between them, but all other
commands operate on the main stack.

It was the first language I created.

**+++ [GitLab repository](https://gitlab.com/TheWastl/Reflections)
+++ [Online interpreter](http://thewastl.gitlab.io/Reflections/reflections.html)
+++ [Documentation](https://gitlab.com/TheWastl/Reflections/wikis/home)
+++ [Chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76946/reflections)
+++**

Answer (score 1):

## [Ahead](https://github.com/ajc2/ahead)

Ahead is a [fungeoid](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fungeoid) I've been developing on and off for a few months. It is very much in a "perpetually-rolling release" state of development and features are still being specified and implemented, but what's there right now is very solid. Ahead is [available on TIO.](https://tio.run/#ahead)

### Standout Features

Ahead is inspired by [Befunge](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge) and [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish) but takes its own liberties with the 2D grid style. Most obviously, most of the symbols are different (sorry polyglots!) Just for the sake of an example, [here's the truth machine](https://tio.run/##S8xITUz5/9@z2N@Bq87O0L/u/38DAA):

```
IsO@
~>1O~
```

---

Rather than wrapping around when the head (or IP) reaches the end of a line, it "bounces off the edge" and begins traveling backwards to the previous cell. The board (program space) is bounded on all sides by the "edge", which is like a bunch of imaginary walls the head can't pass. Here, the `#` symbols are the edge and the `.`s are the space beyond.

```
.........
.#######.
.#IsO@ #.
.#~>1O~#.
.#######.
.........
```

To the head, the edge, and the space beyond, doesn't exist; it is an impenetrable field that is entirely inaccessible. The board is sized exactly to the smallest rectangle required to hold the entire program code, with gaps filled in with space characters, and fixed to that size. The board is not infinite, and combined with the lack of Befunge-style `g` or `p` commands self-modifying programs or those that use the board for storage are extremely difficult to write.

However, these edge bounces can be very useful and interesting tools for head movement, particularly when traveling diagonally.

---

The head can make 90 degree turns to the left or right using `L` or `R`. These are rather self-explanatory; if you're traveling `>` and hit an `L`, you start going `^`.

However, the head can also make 45 degree turns with `l` and `r`. If you're going `>` (or East) and hit an `l`, you start traveling "Northeast"; that is, diagonally up-right. This is the only way to travel diagonally in Ahead (as of now?), and the head can only travel in these eight directions.

---

String state behaves very much like you expect, except it pushes a 0 (or `NUL`) to the stack when you enter. This makes it very convenient to determine where a string ends.

This couples with `W`, which prints characters off the stack until it reaches a 0. The combination of these two makes the [Hello World program](https://tio.run/##S8xITUz5/19JMSWnKD9cQSc/JyfVQync4f9/AA) absolutely trivial:

```
"!dlroW ,olleH"W@
```

---

In general, the running theme of Ahead is to be a twist on traditional fungeoids with a smattering of useful builtins. Before this post gets way too long, you can check the full list of currently-implemented functions on the GitHub wiki (and of course, try them on TIO.) More updates are coming!

Answer (score 1):

## [Turing Machine But Way Worse](https://github.com/MilkyWay90/Turing-Machine-But-Way-Worse)

#### By MilkyWay90 and ASCII_only

When you look at golfing languages, they confuse you and are very hard to learn.

But when you look at practical languages, they don't confuse you (normally) and are easy to learn (normally)

But what about a language which confuses you, but is easy to learn?

This is where Turing Machine But Way Worse comes in.

When I was learning about Turing Machines, I was annoyed by how they couldn't use I/O, so I built a programming language which does!

With the help of ASCII_only, we made a language which processes I/O while still keeping the point of a Turing Machine.

If you look at any submission for Turing Machine But Way Worse, you can see that it is just a lot of numbers. A LOT. But when you learn it, it will be super easy to debug and write your own programs using our debugger built-in.

Answer (score 1):

### [@](https://esolangs.org/wiki/@)

Unlike other submissions, note that there isn't a self-referring pronoun!

@ is a functional language created by [Gemdude46](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/72036/gemdude46) designed for code-golfing.

### Structure of a program

The language is made of a tree of function calls. Each character (with some exceptions) represents a function that may take as many or few arguments as it likes. Arguments are then read from directly after it in the code.

For example:

If instruction A takes 1 argument, B takes 2, C takes 3, and D and E both take none, then the @ code

```
   BADCDBEDE
```

Would be written in many languages like

```
   B(A(D()), C(D(), B(E(), D()), E())))
```

Instruction arguments are evaluated LTR unless the docs explicitly say otherwise. Arguments may not be evaluated at all or may be evaluated more than once.

### Values and data types

@ has the following data types:

number - This is an arbitrary precision rational number.

vector - This is an immutable list of other values of any type.

If anything refers to a string, then it means a vector of codepoints.

Anything enclosed in braces is seen as a string literal. String literals are automatically ended on EOF. Should an EOF be encountered where an instruction should be, Š is used.

### Examples

Hello world:

```
   ħ
```

Cat:

```
   ¤ōč
```

Truth machine:

```
   ?ň¤Ō10
```

### Links

- [Page](https://esolangs.org/wiki/@)
- [Repo](https://github.com/gemdude46/atLang)

Answer (score 1):

## [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w)

> [Whoever said golfing languages had far to many useless builtins?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/86606/85052)

I'm afraid I also agree with that quote. In fact, I created W *because* I feel that golfing languages have *way* too many built-ins, and most of them are not useful at all in practical golfing competitions.

I initially tried to learn Pyth, but its syntax is too inconsistent for me to easily master. Therefore I decided to create a "more consistent" version of postfix Pyth which only uses postfix notation.

And then I decided to remove all the "inconsistent" accumulator and temporary storage stuff, in order to start a thought experiment. In [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/118111/tips-for-storage-in-a-golfing-language) it has been suggested that temporary storage is neccecary. However W only has *one single* stack with no temporary storage.

---

Example: This outputs an array of each character code of the input:

```
C
```

Output for `Hello, World!`: `[72,101,108,108,111,44,32,87,111,114,108,100,33]`

---

- [Interpreter](Not yet on TIO... :) )
- [Github (you should totally star W if you like it)](https://github.com/A-ee/w)
- [Documentation](https://github.com/A-ee/w/wiki)

Comment: It's funny - your description reminds me a lot of the original motivation for Pyth. Good luck!

Comment: I initially tried to learn Pyth, but its syntax is too inconsistent for me to easily master. Therefore I decided to create a "more consistent" version of postfix Pyth which only uses postfix notation.

Answer (score 1):

## [TalkingHead](https://github.com/PlaceReporter99/talking-head)

The very limited language where you golf by talking faster. [Don’t just take my word that it’s a novel language.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63672679#63672679)

Answer (score 0):

## [Noether](https://github.com/beta-decay/noether)

Noether is stack-based, semi-golfing language designed by myself.

Based mainly on Fourier, Noether is stack-based and uses reverse polish notation. These two facts make Noether a lot more powerful than Fourier, mainly because it means that strings and integers can be stored and manipulated alike.

Similarly, Noether's functions are overloaded based on the type of the arguments. For example, the function `L` has two functions:

- When passed a string, `L` returns the length of the string.
- When passed a number, `L` returns the base 10 logarithm of the number

As a result, Noether can be used more widely and is wholly more usable language whilst still being quite similar to Fourier.

### Links:

- **Github link**: https://github.com/beta-decay/noether
- **Online interpreter:** https://beta-decay.github.io/noether

Answer (score 0):

### [TLDCode](https://github.com/Thelonedevil/TLDCode)

Created by [The_Lone_Devil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/46866/the-lone-devil) (Me) and is a (WIP) stack based language.

The name is likely to change one day when I think of a good one.

I created it as something to work on during some downtime at work, and to learn Kotlin a bit better (the language the interpreter is written in).

There is some documentation, as well as a Kotlin based interpreter over on the [Github page](https://github.com/Thelonedevil/TLDCode)

Some features include

- User functions, by pushing a string containing code onto the top of the stack, and then storing the top of the stack into a named variable, you can push the variable onto the stack and eval it to execute.
- Immutable variables, once a variable is set, only a copy can be pushed onto the stack, they can never change.

Comment: The name sounds like "Too long; didn't code" :p

Comment: @RedClover TL;DR is the first thing I thought of when I saw the title.

Answer (score 0):

## MashedPotatoes

MashedPotatoes is a register-based esoteric programming language designed by yours truly that "mashes" together several syntactic constructs from other languages and alters their meaning significantly.

The central theme of MashedPotatoes is to confuse color-coding parsers while making code difficult to read and frustrating to write. Almost every construct in the language is borrowed syntactically from another language but does not serve its original purpose. Examples:

- The text `--help` is the numerical literal representing zero. This is the only numerical literal whose value does not change.
- The Perl "baby carriage" operator `@{[ ... ]}` returns the negative of the argument
- The Common Lisp style print statement `(format t " ... ")` is the basic looping construct in MashedPotatoes.

Additionally, to make sure programmers don't become complacent, many syntactic constructs change meaning each time you use them. There are three registers: the accumulator, the counter, and the evaluator. However, none of these registers can be accessed directly. They are accessed by the following expressions.

- `STDERR`, which returns the accumulator the first time it is used in a program, the counter the second, and the evaluator the third.
- `$[`, which returns the counter, then the evaluator and then the accumulator.
- `` `uniq -c` `` (the backticks are significant) refers to the evaluator, then the accumulator, and then the counter.

So to refer to a register, you have to find an identifier that is currently pointing to that register. This design decision ensures that programmers who are refactoring code still have a sufficiently challenging task. Likewise, labels are used to activate several commands. There are three labels (plus a fourth "nullary" label), and each label has four names. Referring to a label by the wrong name is a syntax error, and the name changes every time you use it.

**Resources:**

- [Official interpreter](https://github.com/Mercerenies/mashed-potatoes) (written in Python)
- [Esolangs page](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MashedPotatoes)

**FAQs:**

- **Why?** I got bored at work one day and this was the result.
- **Are there any example programs?** Yes, the Esolang page has a well-documented [factorial program](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MashedPotatoes#Factorial) and a (less well-documented) [Fibonacci program](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MashedPotatoes#Fibonacci_Sequence).
- **What does "Hello World" look like in MashedPotatoes?** No idea. I tried once to write it and eventually gave up. If you can write "Hello World" in MashedPotatoes, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

## ALPHA

I made up this esoteric language by me, SnivyDroid, on the 27th of January, 2018 after reading about alphabetical-based esolangs like alphuck, it is just pseudo-code currently although I am working on structuring a interpreter with what little knowledge I have about parsing and interpreting code.

## Basic Syntax

ALPHA Revolves around 1-character alphabetical mirrored commands, basically you start a command with the corresponding letter and you end it with the corresponding letter

*Starting a line*

```
KK
```

*Printing a statement*

```
KMSDFOODMK
```

*Hello World*

```
KMDHELLO WORLDDMK
```

Here is the entire command set I made up:

```
A=Not Equal
B=Subtract
C=If
D=String
E=Divide
F=Multiply
G=Equal
H=Add
I=For loop
J=Variable
K=Line
L=While loop
M=Print
N=Break
O=Not
P=Integer
Q=Take input
R=Do
S=Array
T=Join
U=Set
V=Pop
W=Then
X=Modulo
Y=Append
Z=Special
```

(Yes, I specifically shuffled the commands to make it painful)

Z would act as a way to access different sets of commands to extend into more specific functions.

Hopefully I should be able to write an interpreter one day, and if anyone has any advice on what I can use to make one that would be neat.

Here are some other examples I whipped up:

*Wide text generator*

```
KMHTD DQQTD DHMK
KK - Start line
KM - Start print
KMH - Start Add
KMHT - Start Join
KMHTD D - Add String arg
KMHTD DQQ - Add input arg
KMHTD DQQT - End Join
KMHTD DQQTD D - Add String arg
KMHTD DQQTD DH - End Add
KMHTD DQQTD DHM - End print
KMHTD DQQTD DHMK - End line
```

*Generate a N-Length list of N*

```
KUJAJSSUK
KMIUJCJUUJIJQQUIRYSSVIVYRMK
```

Any feedback?

Comment: How does `KMDHELLO WORLDDMK` work? Since the string indicator is `D`, wouldn't the string truncate at `HELLO WORL`, then begin another string?

Comment: I created a buffer called ZA that will escape strings. A single ZA will just act as a normal set of characters but ZA surrounding any characters will escape them from the string.

Answer (score 0):

## [BFZip](https://github.com/robbie0630/BFZip)

While not technically a programming language, I made this to help Brainfuck golfers to reduce their byte count.

Unfortunately, there are some glaring [issues](https://github.com/robbie0630/BFZip/issues) that make this unusable. I would appreciate any help with fixing them.

You can still calculate the bytes hypothetically if you use this formula, where `n` is the original byte count: `⌈3⋅n⁄8⌉`

Comment: This seems a bit like [CompressedFuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/CompressedFuck) (which also uses a 3-bit encoding, albeit a different one) and [Spoon](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Spoon) (which uses a variable-length Huffman encoding for maximum compression, and also has some extra commands)

Comment: @EsolangingFruit I didn't even know that CompressedFuck existed, now I feel like I did all that work for nothing :(

Comment: You could generalize your implementation into an arbitrary BF translator to handled BFZip, CompressedFuck, Spoon, etc.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pixiedust](https://github.com/The-Snide-Sniper/pixiedust)

### By [Stephen Leppik](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/62402/stephen-leppik)

If you ask a 5-year-old what tells a computer what to do, they'll probably answer along the lines of "fairies and pixie dust". With the existence of this assembly-like language, that's not entirely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

## ACCUMULATOR

This was my first language, and mainly it was intended as practice for my computer exam.

It's online at [this page](https://rizwan342.github.io/accumulator.html) and its esolangs page is https://esolangs.org/wiki/ACCUMULATOR.

This is unusable for programming, but has <s>one</s> two answers on CGCC. It is *not* a golfing language, but as my website says, "a programming language that is only useful for [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) challenges with a fixed number as the output". It has only 4 functions, and interpreters and more can be found on the esolangs page.