# Are Non-Programming golf puzzles allowed?

Tags: discussion

The name of this Stack Exchange site is "Programming Puzzles and Code golf" but I was wondering if other types of similar golf (not the sport) would be allowed or welcomed for questions.  In particular I was thinking about proof golf.  Where a statement in Propositional Calculus or First Order Logic is given and the goal is to create a proof using as few axioms of the system.

These types of puzzles are very much like code golfing in practice but they are certainly not code golf or a programing puzzle.  I thought it might make a fun one-off challenge, but on the other hand it might be a bit out of scope for this site.

Comment: For the most part, a challenge needs to involve writing code, since that's what most of us are here for. We have a few different challenge types that vary the method or difficulty of the problem solving required, though.

Comment: History lesson: This site is (kind of) an off-shoot from Stack Overflow. Certain programming "challenges" were posted on SO, and that gave people the idea to create PPCG as a beta site, which has now graduated.

Comment: Related: [Objective computational challenges without “code”](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/9590/12012)

Comment: Yes, that's a nice question about it. Though it's allowed, you might want to try the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) first, since many users might think it off-topic if not worded well.

Comment: I saw [this shortest logical proof contest](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/812949/24654) on math SE.

Answer (score 44):

### Yes, this is [atomic-code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atomic-code-golf)

Or, it's what atomic code golf should be. Take a look at

- [Multiply with restricted operations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37188/20260)
- [Build a multiplying machine using NAND logic gates](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12261/20260)
- [Implement an 8 bit adder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37071/implement-an-8-bit-adder)

All of them define a mini-language by listing a limited set of allowed operations, and ask for a task to be done in as few of these operations as possible.

In the same vein, one could have a challenge to construct a regular pentagon in as few ruler-and-compass operations, writing out the operation like "draw a circle with the given point and the current radius", "mark a point at the intersection of two lines", and so on. One could write an interpreter for this language, where each operation is a code instruction, the current picture is the program state, and so on. The result is a challenge like code golf, except that:

- All submissions must be in the given invented language
- Rather than minimizing characters, one minimizes operations

Your first reaction might be, "but that's not a programming language, it's geometry!". But why? Perhaps the [NAND gate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12261/20260) language feels like programming because logic gates happen to be what computers use. It's just association. We already use esoteric languages where a "program" is

- [A list of fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FRACTRAN)
- [Text editor instructions](http://www.vim.org/)
- [A bitmap that look like abstract art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esoteric_programming_language#Piet)
- [A board for marbles](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6949/20260)

And anyone is free to make their own language. Using weird languages is a point of pride in the community. So let's not call something "not programming" for not looking like a typical programming language.

Formal proofs, which OP used as an example, have a particularly close relationship to programming. The [Curry-Howard correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence), aka the proofs as programs interpretation, gives a formal mathematical equivalence between proofs and programs. A challenge to prove a statement in a formal system could be rephrased as writing a program that instantiates a given type.

Comment: The _One could write an interpreter for this language_ part is both _essential_ (we usually require a language to have an interpreter, although I can't find the meta post) and possibly _hard_ (write an interpreter just for a challenge)

Answer (score 0):

## No.

We're a programming site. Thus, all submissions (and therefore challenges) must involve the use of code*.

<sup>* A programming language which is executable through a digital interpreter.</sup>

Comment: So if the challenge author wrote an online interpreter where the characters 0-9 applied the corresponding axioms to `(-a) * (-a)`, it would be acceptable? Why would going through all that effort to create a digital interpreter instead of writing out the steps change the underlying question? And if it’s still not acceptable, how is it different from creating other programming languages?