# Would this be on topic for this site?

Tags: discussion

### Disprove that this code generate valid n^2 x n^2 Sudoku Grids

I'm complete with my Sudoku Project and others have been skeptical that I can generate pre-filled valid Sudoku grids in poly-time.

Now, disprove formally that this code won't print one out of n! valid grids sequentially of 9 x 9, 12 x 12, ..... ---- > n^2 x n^2

Remember, the rules for a *12 x 12*. it would be *3 x 4* squares. You'll have to know how a valid Sudoku grid would map out for a n x n. eg. *9 x 9* would be *3 x 3*.

A 9 x 9 grid would follow a list that has a length of non-repeating 9 elements.

You are asked for input to map out valid grid in O(n^2) time.

HINT: If you generate larger grids than 9 x 9, you'll need to make sure your input is given for human readability eg.**['[01]','[02]'...]**

```
print('enter with [1,2,3...] brackets')
tup = input()[1:-1].split(',')
x = input('Enter mapping valid Sudoku eg. 3 for 9 x 9:')
e = input('Enter 9 for 9 x 9 ...12 for 12 x 12:')
f = input('Enter 3 if its a 9 x 9 ... n^2 x n^2:')
x = int(x)
e = int(e)
f = int(f)
squares = []
for index in range(len(tup)):
  tup.append(tup.pop(0))
  squares.append(tup.copy())

    #Everything below here is just printing
for s in range(x):
      for d in range(0,e,f):
        for si in range(s,e,f):
          for li in range(d,d+f):
            print(squares[si][li], end = '')
        print('')
```

If you can't disprove, then prove it. And, if it is non-finite subsets of n^2 x n^2 but with some sets not mappable then prove that as well.

Gratitude and Appreciation would be much given as an award.

I have a link to an improved code-https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/221537/194047

**instructions**

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tbw1995/Sudoku-Solver-Constrained/master/Readme

Comment: Regardless of this being off-topic, thanks for asking about it first! It's much easier for both sides to ask whether it's on-topic before having your question be downvoted & closed after the fact.

Comment: Isn't [proof-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/proof-golf/info) on-topic?

Comment: @Adám Probably, would require some kind of predicate logic with a lim function or something like that. I'm not good at math that's why I wanted to share.

Comment: By the way, this program does not run in n^2 time - the output is size n^4, so it's obviously not in n^2 time. It looks like it runs in n^6 time. Also, there is a very simple algorithm that runs in n^4 time to output a valid n^2 x n^2 solved sudoku grid: For the first row, output the numbers in order: `1234...` For the next row, rotate by n: `n, n+1, n+2, ...`. For the first n rows, increase the rotation amount by n each time. For the next set of n rows, start at a rotation of 1, then increase by n each time. In general, the `i*n+j`th row should be rotated by `j*n+i`, where `i<n`, `j<n`.

Comment: Finally, neither this simpler program nor your original are "poly-time", since the input is of size `log n`, and the runtime is polynomial in `n`, and therefore exponential in the size of the input.

Comment: @isaacg I don't see how its exponential if  the input x exceeds in length compared to what the other variables are doing. Take a look at this link. It should be O(n^4) by bitlength. https://i.imgur.com/VvXh4bA.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Stack Exchange, and thanks for asking! Unfortunately, this question wouldn't be on-topic here, since we generally accept two kinds of questions:

- Challenges where the answerers are asked to write code to solve a specified task. These are competitions with a specified objective winning criterion (i.e. the measure of comparison between two answers to find out which one performs better or if they tie, also included as a tag on the question, usually [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)).
- Non-challenge questions where the asker wants [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) on how to optimize their code so that it compares better with a specified objective winning criterion. We also have [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) questions for golfing tricks in specific languages, as well as a general one.

For more details, read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in our Help Center.

Comment: So [proof-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/proof-golf/info) is off-topic?

Comment: @Adám "generally" :P More specifically, [tag:proof-golf] is an exception, and is currently very rare (only one user has posted such challenges). Obviously, exceptions always exist. Another example is [tag:showcase], where there's no winning criterion at all, because the community has decided to keep it open. As for your intention in your comment under the question, no, that's not [tag:proof-golf], where "There should be a complete and unambiguous set of well-defined axioms and a definition of what constitutes a single valid step in the proof."

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Oh, I'm just in time! :) Wow, maybe in a special case this question could be asked (after some improvements) to show what kind of proof I'm looking for. Predicate Logic with lim function was the best I got, but it only should have proved that non-finite n x m Sudokus can be generated by this algorithm. But, it wasn't enough to prove n^2 x n^2.

Comment: @TravisWells That's... not really encouraged. Even if you manage to convert your code into a mathematical formulation, a [tag:proof-golf] question isn't intended for asking for a proof or disproof, but not knowing which one is true. Instead, [tag:proof-golf] is for challenges where you're given some axioms and a theorem that's known to be provable only with the given axioms, and you're asked to use the least steps possible (lemmas don't shorten the proof) to prove the theorem.

Comment: To help clarify, any challenge in which the goal is simply "be the first person to provide a valid answer" is considered off-topic.

Comment: It is worth noting that a proof in sufficiently mathemetized systems is a computer program ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence)) in a different sort of language.  [Which is, by the way, the justification for it being on topic in the first place](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10290/56656).

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic The slight difference from [tag:atomic-code-golf] is that the "program" is actually a sequence of axioms (proof) that doesn't execute as a program, that's why it's kinda an exception. :P