# What's required for me to use my own language?

Tags: discussion

I recently "finished" my own BrainFuck variant ([ezfuck](https://github.com/carcigenicate/ezfuck)), and wanted to try using it for golfing.

Assuming the version of the language I'm using predates the challenge, are there any other restrictions?

On the Github page, I supplied a .jar that starts a REPL capable of running code. A jar could be created manually as well since all the source code is available, and it can be run directly, from say, a REPL in an IDE.

Is this enough? I'm assuming I have to supply a way for people to test the code, but what exactly is required for that? Obviously it would be nice if I had a site containing an interpreter, but I'm not at that point yet.

Comment: I think that if there is a freely available interpreter, such as what you provide on Github, it should be fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have the language published somewhere (GitHub is fine), then you're good to go! Right now, you already have the crucial pieces, and those are:

- The code is freely viewable,
- There is a real implementation,
- And there is an interpreter that could be downloaded and ran by anyone who wants to test and verify that your solution is real. (Binary or source code are both acceptable)

These three things are plenty. For what it's worth, I submitted answers in two of my own languages before hosting their interpreters online. (V, and Brain-flak).

If you would like to make it more *"official"*, you could always add it to [What programming languages have been created by PPCG users?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6918/31716), but this is by no means a requirement. Just a fun step and a nice way to show off what your language does.

At some point, it would be nice to have it easily testable online, but this is absolutely not a requirement. If you would like, one nice resource is [Try it online](https://tryitonline.net), which hosts *many* PPCG-made languages. So far, I have added two of my own languages to the site, and each time it is a surprisingly quick and easy process. If you would like to add it, you should ping @Dennis in [the Try It Online chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44255/talk-tryitonline-net) to ask for more details.

Comment: Awesome, thank you.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Additionally, I would also say that publishing it on GitHub has an advantage in that it has revision history, so you can show that your answer (or at least the current revision of it) predates the challenge.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Ya, although I just started using version control like 2 weeks ago, so I'm not super familiar with it yet. So far, once I get a branch working, I just overwrite the master with it and move on, so I don't have any version numbers to reference. The best I could do is say to use the version of the code with commits that predate the challenge.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I've always used commit numbers rather than version numbers when I've needed to specify a particular version of Pyth. It's straightforward and visible to everyone, which is perfect.

Comment: @isaacg That makes sense. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: "The code is freely viewable", is this the languges code or the answers?