# Specific Languages

Tags: discussion, code-golf, answers

In the Code Golf Overflow, can your answers be written in any language unless otherwise specified by the OP?

Or do they have to be written in any specific language?

Comment: You can answer in pretty much any language you want if the asker didn't specify a language. See [this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/what-are-programming-languages?rq=1) to understand if a language is "valid" according to most people here. Also know that you can't answer a challenge with a language/version younger than the challenge itself, unless specified otherwise.

Comment: @Fatalize So, if a question was asked when VC#2010 was being used then I can't use VC#2015 to answer it?

Comment: @EvanManning No one will be bothered if you do.

Comment: @EvanManning No one will really care in this case. The rule is established so that people don't create new languages/functions just to win a challenge.

Comment: You should not use a language feature that is newest than the question. C# 6 has many features that was not present in previous version, and you should avoid them answering older questions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Yes! They can (usually) be in any language.

Submissions can use any programming language that meets [our criteria for qualifying as a language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2073/20469). We also require that the version of the language you use be released *prior* to the posting of the challenge. This ensures that people don't see a challenge and implement a feature in their language just to be competitive in that challenge.

Language-specific or language-restricted challenges are generally frowned upon here, so it's not often that you'll find a challenge where you can't use your favorite language.

Comment: Unless, of course, the language is limited in its ability to perform the challenge...

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Excellent point.

Comment: `We also require that the version of the language you use be released prior to the posting of the challenge.` It's worth noting that this rule is overridden in catalog challenges.

Comment: @Mego Another excellent point.

Comment: Since this is being linked to, I believe the requirement that a language version be released prior to the challenge being posted has been removed altogether, for all challenge types. I can't find the relevant meta post though.