# What constitutes programming for the purposes of this site?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, challenges, scope

According to our [Help Center](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (emphasis mine),

> Programming Puzzles & Code Golf is for **programming** contests and challenges.

Sounds simple enough, and 99 times out of 100 it is. But there are certain challenges which don't really require writing *code*, at least in the most traditional sense. Here are a few examples:

- [Build a minifloat adding machine using NAND logic gates](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/26194/20469)
- [building circuit for divisibility by 3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/24834/20469)
- [Build a 4-vertex Connectedness Tester using NAND gates](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69912/20469)

Given that all challenges here must be *programming* challenges, how do we define *programming*? This is an important distinction for drawing a line between on- and off-topic challenges.

Comment: [Related, now-deleted meta question.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8069/3808)

Comment: From googling "define programming": `instructions for the automatic performance of a task into a computer or other machine.` seems to fit well enough

Comment: @Doᴡɴɢᴏᴀᴛ Sure, but consider the challenges I linked. Does writing writing a series of logic gates fit that description?

Comment: @AlexA. `a control mechanism to complete a task`? I'd consider a series of logic gates a "control mechanism"

Answer (score 8):

### Making a circuit is programming

[Brainfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck) is definitely programming, and it's a bunch of register move commands. So is [bit hacking](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37071/20260) and other kinds of [atomic code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atomic-code-golf). Think of logic gates the same way -- a low-level Turing-tarpit "esolang".

All the examples in question are about circuits, so I'll just leave it at that.

Comment: This is pretty much what I was wondering, despite the question being phrased in more general terms.

Comment: Hit the nail on the head here; great answer. It's also worth mentioning that NAND (and NOR) gates are [functionally complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness), and if you can have an unlimited number of them, that's enough for Turing completeness ([related SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908893/what-logic-gates-are-required-for-turing-completeness)).

Answer (score 6):

### Anything that is acceptable by [our rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/what-are-programming-languages)

[@xnor's answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8185/45941) does a good job of addressing the specific questions asked, but I want to create a more general answer.

The hard and fast rule is, if the system can do all the things listed in the [consensus answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2073/45941), it's valid. The system doesn't have to be code; it could be digital logic, or a logical system encoded using [Gödel numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering). So long as the system is consistent (always gives the same output for the same input(s)) and can perform all of the tasks listed in the linked answer, it's kosher.

Digital logic using any [functionally complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness) set of logic gates is programming, since digital logic is a Turing-complete system with unlimited gates.