# Is Wolfram rule 126 a programming language?

Tags: discussion

According to our site's [definition of a programming language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2073/20283) a language needs to be capable of addition of natural numbers and primality testing of natural numbers. Of the [elementary cellular automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_cellular_automaton), some are periodic and others are chaotic. Rule 110, which is in some sense near the border between periodic and chaotic, is [known to be Turing complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_110). Rule 54 is rumoured to be Turing complete but not yet known to be.

I suspect that rule 126 is not Turing complete. I also suspect that it is not capable of addition or primality testing. However, I do not have a proof either way.

How should such a rule be treated? Should a language be assumed valid until it can be proved that it does not meet our requirements? Or should it be assumed invalid until it can be proved that it does meet our requirements?

---

<sub>This question was prompted by an [old answer on a recently active challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6306/20283). The answer has since been deleted.</sub>

Comment: It's not directly an answer to the question, but a related question: where's the interpreter or compiler? That's also a practical requirement for considering something to be a programming language.

Comment: Yes, how would answers in any Wolfram rule be scored (or written, for that matter)?

Comment: That's a good point. For those rules which do meet our requirements (for example, the Turing complete ones) I guess the language would be "Implementation X of rule 110". Maybe an [implementation from PPCG...](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/34505/20283)

Comment: I guess the score for golf would be either the number of digits in the binary input, or the number of bytes required to describe that binary number (depending on what the interpreter takes as input). If there's dispute on how a particular interpreter should be scored that would need a separate meta question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do submissions have to be answered with a programming language?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10421/do-submissions-have-to-be-answered-with-a-programming-language)

Comment: I disagree that the two are "duplicates" per se, but since the answers to the question linked by @pppery make this entire question null and void, I've cast to VTC

Answer (score 16):

### It's invalid until proven valid

If you cannot prove that a language can do addition and primality testing, it's not a programming language by our definition.