# "Windows" as a programming language?

Tags: discussion, policy, answers

I was going to give the green tick mark to the winning submission of [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/111380/i-copied-my-password-to-the-clipboard-can-you-delete-it), but I am unsure what to do. The shortest submission is [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111883/36398), which claims to use "Windows language", but I doubt that Windows can be considered a language.

What do you think? I know [our official definition](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2073/36398) of programming language, but I don't see if/how it allows or rules out "Windows" as a language.

Comment: If anything, I'd say that Windows is an interpreter. We don't go around calling "gcc" a language...

Comment: @AdmBorkBork I think that argument may not be valid. We do define languages by their implementations. So there's "GCC C", "TCC C", etc

Comment: And what language is being implemented by windows.

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk _That_'s a better argument

Comment: Yeah, that's a better way of phrasing what I was intending.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork Your wording was fine. I got confused because I thought GCC was a C compiler. Now I see it includes many languages

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk Batch

Comment: @ГригорийПерельман I don't believe that printscreen is a valid batch command. Want to try again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we allow "Windows" as a programming language on the basis that it contains a shell, why not allow "Computer" as a programming language on the basis that you can run an OS with a shell on it? And then the whole question of what is or isn't a programming language becomes moot, because if it can form part of a system which includes a computer then it's ok...

So no, it's absurd to claim that Windows is a language.

Comment: I have a computer, so that makes me a programming language, right?

Comment: @mbomb007, exactly.

Comment: Aren't exe files what makes windows a language?  It contains commands that windows parses and executes.  (I agree though, that keyboard shortcuts isn't an "input" to windows)

Comment: @NathanMerrill Windows doesn't do anything besides loading the executable and any libraries it needs. Your processor does the actual computation. The machine language is the actual programming language here - Windows and your processor are the tools used to execute the program. When writing a C program, you wouldn't consider bash to be the programming language, but it is a tool you use to compile, link, and execute the program.