# Do different ImageMagick tools count as their own languages?

Tags: discussion, code-golf

Here is an answer that I made recently: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181416/70328

A commenter suggested that I could remove `convert` from my code, and use `ImageMagick convert` as the programming language. I think that, since you cannot get `convert` without the rest of ImageMagick, it should not be counted as a separate programming language. Who is right here?

Comment: I would argue that this is definitely ImageMagick, but I'm not sure. Do you have any other "tools" in IM? This might depend on "tool" vs "command/function/keyword".

Comment: yes, ImageMagick comes with several commands including `convert`, `animate`, `compare`, `composite`, `conjure`, [etc.](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-tools.php)

Comment: I'm assuming that those are all pre-installed (they come with IM) not 'modules'/'libraries' that need to be 'imported' or similar?

Comment: yes, they all come when you install imagemagick

Comment: Seriously, whether the `convert` is included doesn't affect the score relative to other `convert` answers (if any), and answers in that "language" are not comparable with other languages anyway...

Answer (score 4):

## It's irrelevant

On PPCG, using home-brewed languages is allowed. Nothing (well, except for the reasons below) stops you from making a new language that is *really* good at solving a very limited set of challenges. `ImageMagick convert` would be such a language. Feel free to count it as a separate language if the arguments below do not sway you.

- Arguably, this falls under [this loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1071/32352).
- There are two aspects to competing on PPCG. The first is creating the best entry in your language of choice. The second is picking the right language for the job.<sup>+</sup> By using `ImageMagick convert` you may have done really well on the latter part, but I would argue that you will have almost zero competition on the first part. If you enjoy using `ImageMagick convert` as a separate language, you may also want to consider competing in local sports event aimed at children age 6 through 8.
- The income of Fake Magic Internet Points will decrease. FMIPs are given out when other people like your approach. Using a language that is stupidly specific might even result in negative FMIPs. I theorise that the amount of FMIPs is related to how universal you show that your language is. For example, if you solve all the typical questions like Hello World, Fibonacci, Primality tests, FizzBuzz, Anagram check, cat, etc., using `ImageMagick convert`, the aforementioned loophole is clearly negated, and you could expect your FMIP count to increase once more.

<sup>+ For example, I program in MATL and Octave. My goal is to outgolf other MATL and Octave entries respectively, but when I use MATL, I do want to see if I can beat Jelly or 05AB1E, and when I use Octave, I like to see if I can outgolf R or Python.</sup>

Comment: hmm... you make a good point. The language should technically be `bash + ImageMagick` then, wouldn't it? After all, I've seen python answers that have `import PIL` in them or something like that, so this isn't exactly different except for the fact that it doesn't include an import statement...

Answer (score 2):

## Yes it is a valid language, but you do not need to use it

This does count as a language for the purposes of competing on this site. It is trivial to write an interpreter for this new language, so it is valid. Historically we required a language to meet certain criteria to be valid, but [the most recent answer to "What are programming languages?"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7518/20283) has strong consensus for relaxing these requirements.

However, there are also many other "languages" that could be defined like that, and although valid they rarely get used in practice. Just because it's technically valid doesn't make it a fun or interesting thing to do. You are under no obligation to use this alternative language just because it would give a lower score. Similarly you are under no obligation to switch to a golfing language even though that would likely give a lower score in many cases. Enjoy golfing in your language(s) of choice. For each one, strive for the lowest score *in that language*.

Comment: I guess I should rephrase the question, which was a simple question about whether I should include `convert ` in the byte count or not. Good answer, though

Comment: Thanks. In that case, the short answer would be "Yes, include `convert` in the bytecount, unless you are going to change to a different language"

Answer (score 1):

Using `convert` is not a separate language, but merely providing arguments to the program. I believe the commands are not flexible or expressive enough to be considered a "programming language" rather than a set of flags/instructions, though the precise definition of "programming language" is hazy.