# Useful External Resources

Tags: discussion, faq

There are a bunch of external resources that are either used very often by this community or are directly related to it. This post contains the most relevant ones to make them more discoverable for new users.

Here is how this will work: put each resource in a separate answer, linking to it at the top. You can use the answer body to explain what it is and how it's useful. Also edit a link into the list below for quick access. The idea is that the votes will let the most useful resources bubble up to the top. If an answer gets too many downvotes, it will probably be removed to keep the list useful and the noise low.

Please also make sure that the type of resource isn't covered by the related meta posts at the bottom (for example links to online testing environments).

#### Quick access links

- [The Nineteenth Byte Data Explorer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10352/8478)
- [Graduation Design Userscript](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7955/31716)
- [Byte Counter - ETHproductions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10358/8478)

#### See also

Some other meta posts that list external resources of more specific purpose:

- [Where to find an online testing environment for specific programming languages?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/202/8478)
- [Installation and testing instructions for specific programming languages](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1213/8478)

Answer (score 14):

## [Byte Counter](https://ethproductions.github.io/bytes/)

A byte counter made by [ETHproductions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions) that currently supports 20 different encodings (UTF-8, UTF-16, ISO-8859-1, CP437, ASCII and many more!), has [permalinks](https://ethproductions.github.io/bytes/?e=utf-8&t=permalink%20test) and a bookmarklet to count chars and UTF-8 bytes on the fly.

If you have any feature suggestions or encoding requests, leave a comment below.

Comment: Huh, this is really nice (and a much nicer URL than the other one, too). Since the other one provides only a subset of this, I'll just link to this one.

Comment: Hey, thanks for posting this :)

Comment: Inspired by this one? https://mothereff.in/byte-counter

Comment: @ETHproductions I think it'd be helpful if your byte counter would save the previous codepage selection similar to what the link above does. It also saves the contents of the textarea. If you added these, I'd consider using yours instead.

Comment: @mbomb007 Yes, and great suggestions. I'll see if I can add these in today.

Comment: @mbomb007 The byte counter now saves your most recent text and encoding.

Answer (score 13):

### [The Nineteenth Byte Data Explorer](http://ppcg.starmaninnovations.com/tnbde/)

[El'endia Starman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12914/elendia-starman) was interested in various statistics about the messages that users post daily, so he wrote a data explorer which lets you query the transcript of our main chatroom with SQL. It also doubles as a very handy chat search as it is far more flexible than the built-in search feature.

**Demonstration of searching capability:**

- [Certain words](http://ppcg.starmaninnovations.com/tnbde/#hQLCQIdmLQ) ("should've"; compare [SE's built-in search](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=should%27ve&user=&room=240))
- [Multiple words](http://ppcg.starmaninnovations.com/tnbde/#eNvBSRuyQq) ("hello bye"; compare [SE's chat search](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=hello+bye&user=&room=240))
- [Substrings](http://ppcg.starmaninnovations.com/tnbde/#AuBxcrtxzw) ("string")
- [Excluding words](http://ppcg.starmaninnovations.com/tnbde/#VtgIjhblLM) ("night" without "good")
- [Punctuation](http://ppcg.starmaninnovations.com/tnbde/#bIllslpWkH) ("???")
- [Code snippets](http://ppcg.starmaninnovations.com/tnbde/#VzvkSFPCEd) ("%10")
- [Regex](http://ppcg.starmaninnovations.com/tnbde/#blrvpDvXFO) (messages with Try It Online links)

These kinds of queries use [PostgreSQL's pattern matching features](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html).

There are also [additional useful queries](http://ppcg.starmaninnovations.com/usefulqueries) that you can peruse if you want to see what queries have already been written or if you want to write one, so you can build off of what has already been written.

Answer (score 7):

## [Graduation Design Userscript](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7955/31716)

A little while ago, some users started talking about what we would like to see in the design of our site once it gets a custom design. User [Downgoat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/40695/downgoat), along with the help of some others put all of these idea together into a single script that customizes the appearance of the site, both on main and meta.

### Pictures:

#### Main

[image]

### Installation

You can install [Tampermonkey](//tampermonkey.net) which supports a *ton* of browsers (probably will include yours). You can then just use [this link](//rawgit.com/vihanb/PPCG-Design/master/ppcg.user.js) to install the script (or copy-paste the code into a new script).

Answer (score 4):

### [Code Page Keyboard](http://mego.github.io/CodePageKeyboard/)

Need to write something in a specific code page, and don't want to have to change your keyboard layout, learn a bunch of special codes, or copy-and-paste each individual character? This is the tool for you! Simply select a code page, click the buttons, and copy the text at the bottom. A *huge* number of code pages are supported, including:

- ASCII
- CP437
- CP1252
- Latin-1
- Jelly

Comment: It should be noted that though certain unprintables are shown in a code page, they will not be entered into the textarea, nor will they be copied/pasted correctly. The easiest example is `NUL` on the ASCII code page.

Comment: It also runs pretty slowly when changing code pages.

Comment: Also when you switch from e.g. Jelly to ASCII the characters in 80-FF range doesn't disappear.

Comment: @user202729 Please open issues on GitHub so I can keep track of them easier.

Answer (score 2):

### [Byte counter](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter)

A minimalist online byte counter which gives you both the character count and the UTF-8 byte count of its input. Note that not all answers will use UTF-8 encoding, but it's very handy for those that do.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this is a *UTF-8* byte counter, so for languages like Jelly, V,  05AB1E, Actually etc. the displayed byte count will be too high.

Answer (score 2):

## [ByteCounter](http://mego.github.io/ByteCounter/)

Yet another byte counter... However, this one works a bit differently than the rest. You input text, and it gives you the length of the text in bytes in *every possible encoding* (so long as the encoding contains all of the characters in the text).

Permalinks will be added soon for sharing results.

Comment: I'd just like to note that thing took so long the first time, I figured it was b0rken and had time to write up a GitHub issue about the problem before it worked. Now it's working faster -- just for anyone who tries it.

Comment: @cat Yeah, it's an issue with the library I use for it. I'm working on some speed up changes, but I haven't had much time lately to work on them. After the first run, your cache should make things better.